# Quais as diferenças entre Git, SVN e CVS?

Tags: git, versionamento, svn

Quais as vantagens, limitações e principais diferenças entre esses 3 sistemas de versionamento, Git, SVN e CVS?

Comment: Acho que a resposta dessa pergunta dá um livro inteiro. Mas é uma boa pergunta! =)

Comment: Excelentes respostas aqui abaixo; esta é daquelas perguntas que vira clássico, muitas medalhas e pontos pra todos os envolvidos ;)

Comment: O problema desse tipo de pergunta é que é quase impossível escolher a resposta certa.

Comment: Era interessante comparar também o [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

## CVS

Foi um dos primeiros sistemas de controle de versão a ter fluxos alternativos de desenvolvimento e a permitir livre edição de arquivos somente-texto entre várias pessoas de um mesmo time ao mesmo tempo. A ideia de um repositório dentro das normas do [cvs](/questions/tagged/cvs) é no esquema de árvore, compreendendo um fluxo principal de desenvolvimento (chamado de `trunk`, ou *tronco* em português), fluxos alternativos de desenvolvimento (chamados de `branches`, ou *galhos*), em que são implementadas mudanças em separado do fluxo principal, e `tags` (*etiquetas*, que são revisões dos outros dois fluxos que não podem mais ser alteradas, ideais para indicar versões estáveis).

Possui os seguintes comandos:

- Checkout: normalmente é usado para denominar o primeiro download de um módulo inteiro a partir do repositório CVS.
- Commit: envio das modificações feitas pelo usuário ao repositório CVS.
- Export: é o download de um módulo inteiro a partir de um repositório CVS, sem os arquivos administrativos CVS. Módulos exportados não ficam sob controle do CVS.
- Import: geralmente é usado para designar a criação de um módulo inteiro dentro de um repositório CVS através do upload de uma estrutura de diretórios.
- Update: atualização da cópia local do trabalho através do download das modificações feitas por outros usuários no repositório.
- Merge: é a fusão de modificações feitas por diferentes usuários na cópia local de um mesmo arquivo. Sempre que alguém altera o código, é necessário realizar um update antes do commit, de modo que seja feito o merge — ou a fusão — das mudanças.

Utiliza uma arquitetura cliente-servidor em que todo o código é centralizado. Ideal para desenvolvimento linear, cujos projetos estejam em fase de manutenção ou pequenos melhoramentos.

## SVN

É a evolução do modelo do [cvs](/questions/tagged/cvs) que resolve bem várias limitações do CVS, como a introdução dos comandos <kbd>Rename</kbd> e <kbd>Move</kbd>, que não apenas renomeia/move o arquivo como mantém seu histórico de alterações, o comando `Commit` (de envio de arquivos) ser verdadeiramente atômico, suportando *rollbacks* em caso de falhas e versionamento de arquivos não suportados pelo [cvs](/questions/tagged/cvs), como links simbólicos.

Possui todos os comandos do [cvs](/questions/tagged/cvs) e mais alguns:

- Rename
- Move

Possui também capacidade de guardar metadados dos arquivos e diretórios (extensões ignoradas, histórico de merges, etc.).

## Git

É um controle de versão bastante diferente do [cvs](/questions/tagged/cvs) e [svn](/questions/tagged/svn), pois o modelo de versionamento é descentralizado (não há exatamente um fluxo central, e quando ele existe, não deve ser alterado, recebendo apenas *merges* de outros fluxos de desenvolvimento) e o envio de arquivos é em duas fases:

1. **Commit**, fase em que as alterações são armazenadas apenas localmente;
2. **Push**, fase em que as alterações são enviadas para um servidor que concentra todos os conjuntos de alterações (chamados de *changesets*) que podem ser recombinados entre si livremente.

Como o [git](/questions/tagged/git) não é um servidor de arquitetura linear, é ideal para projetos em início de desenvolvimento em que conflitos são comuns e funcionalidades são desenvolvidas em separado. O processo de *merge* é o mais completo e tolerante dentre os três.

Answer (score 91):

Primeiramente podemos classificar as três ferramentas em duas grandes categorias:

## Sistemas de versionamento centralizados

CVS e SVN possuem um repositório central de onde os usuários fazem o `checkout` e `commit` dos artefatos versionados.

A vantagem dessa abordagem é que você pode ter um controle central sobre os projetos, impor segurança de acesso mais facilmente. Além disso, há a possibilidade de bloquear arquivos (*lock*).

Porém, existem muitas desvantagens. A principal delas é que esse tipo de sistema não escala muito bem, isto é, muitas equipes e projetos no mesmo repositório tendem a deixá-lo lento. Outra desvantagem importante é que os usuários não podem fazer muita coisa *offline*, sendo necessário sempre estar conectado ao servidor central para realizar operações como criar *tags*, *branches*, fazer *merge*, etc.

Além disso, existem diferenças significativas entre CVS e SVN:

- SVN consegue rastrear arquivos renomeados.
- Se versionamento centralizado é lento, o CVS consegue ser mais ainda.
- O `commit` do CVS é por arquivo. Já o SVN consegue agrupar as mudanças de um `commit`, então é possível por exemplo voltar a uma revisão anterior. Isso facilita muito encontrar qual `commit` quebrou o código.

## Sistemas de versionamento distribuídos

No Git, assim como Mercurial e Bazaar, não existe um repositório central. É claro que você pode eleger um como tal, mas cada repositório, mesmo o da máquina do desenvolvedor, contém uma cópia completa e funcional do repositório.

Uma desvantagem desse modelo é que a clonagem inicial do repositório pode demorar bastante, já que não será feita a transferência apenas da cópia atual de cada artefato, mas também do histórico, *tags* e *branches*. Algo que pode minimizar isso é a possibilidade de recuperar partes do repositório seletivamente, como *branches*, tags ou mesmo por data. Mas não sei de detalhes sobre até que ponto isso é implementado em cada um dos sistemas.

Outra desvantagem é a dificuldade de um gerenciamento centralizado e um controle de acesso efetivo, já que os repositórios ficam distribuídos em vários ambientes.

Além disso, nos sistemas de versionamento distribuídos, `commit` e `checkout` são feitos no repositório local de cada ambiente. Após a conclusão do trabalho, com a classe devidamente "commitada", tags "passadas" e "branches mergeadas", o desenvolvedor precisa sincronizar seu repositório local com o repositório remoto. Isso é feito com os comandos `push` (envia atualizações do seu repositório local para o remoto) e `pull` (recupera atualizações do repositório remoto para o local).

É um pouco mais complicado trabalhar com sistemas de versionamento distribuídos, mas as vantagens são muitas:

- Exceto o `pull` inicial, eles são muito mais rápidos do que os sistemas centralizados como CVS e SVN.
- Muitas operações não necessitam de acesso à rede, então o desenvolvedor pode trabalhar *offline*, sincronizando com o repositório remoto apenas quando necessário.
- O desenvolvedor pode trabalhar em modo privado, gerando tags, branches e versões que serão simplesmente descartadas.
- Exceto quando há conflitos, o merge é automático.
- Cada cópia do repositório funciona como um backup do repositório "principal".

Note que existem diferenças entre os sistemas de versionamento distribuídos. Não conheço quase nada do Bazaar, mas posso citar alguns casos interessantes com relação ao Git e o Mercurial:

- O comando `git pull` inclui o `update` e atualiza os arquivos em uso do projeto, então o `pull` do Git é diferente do conceito tradicional de `pull`, sendo equivalente a `pull` + `update`. O `pull` puro seria na verdade `git fetch`.
- No Git, você precisa adicionar manualmente os arquivos novos e alterados ao *staging area* com o comando `git add` para serem "commitados". O Mercurial faz isso automaticamente por padrão.

Comment: +1 por mencionar outros sistemas de versionamento distribuídos.

Comment: +1 Excelente resposta!

Comment: Um ponto interessante é que DCVS atendem necessidades de projetos distribuídos inclusive no sentido físico da coisa. Contribuidores externos em diferentes locais trocando *patches* por email (ou fazendo *forks* e mandando *pull requests* para projetos *upstream*). Uma cadeia complexa de repositórios e hierarquia de revisores e *commiters*, bem como muitos *branches* e *merges* (quem já teve que fazer um *merge* de dois *branches* do SVN sabe o trabalho que isso dá).

Comment: Tanto o Git (iniciado pelo Linus Torvald) quando o Mercurial (Matt Mackall) surgiram em reação a mudança de licença do [BitKeper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitKeeper), uma das primeiras ferramentas que conseguia lidar com os problemas mencionados acima.

Comment: Excelente resposta

Comment: Uma feature interessante que tem no git é o stash.

Answer (score 54):

## Um pouco de história

#### Primórdios

Os sistemas de controle de versão são bem antigos. Alguns dos primeiros conhecidos foram o [CA Software Change Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA_Software_Change_Manager), o [Panvalet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panvalet) e o [SCCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System) em 1972. Só uma década depois surgiu um que formou a base de como conhecemos estes softwares hoje em dia com o [RCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System). Alguns anos depois surgiu uma evolução que tornou o uso praticável. Mas não sem problemas.

#### Produtos evoluídos

O [CVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) foi útil por muito tempo, mas ele carece de funcionalidade mais sofisticadas e principalmente de confiabilidade. É bem verdade que em alguns casos ele até funciona bem. Mas não consigo ver nenhum motivo para escolhê-lo hoje em dia para gerenciar uma base de código sua. No máximo usar um cliente para pegar código de um projeto legado.

Ao longo dos anos 80 e 90 surgiram diversas opções de softwares comerciais como os mais conhecidos [ClearCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_ClearCase), [Visual Source[un]Safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe) e [Perforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce).

Estes sistemas são considerados cliente-servidor, portanto precisa de um repositório central para receber todas as atualizações. Cada um com sua característica, com suas virtudes e defeitos conseguiram melhorar muito o fluxo de trabalho de equipes desenvolvendo softwares.

#### Algo que funciona bem

O CVS fez muito sucesso por ser código aberto, mas tinha muitos defeitos. Não que alguns produtos comerciais (vide piadinha que eu fiz acima) não tenham seu sucesso também. Com isto surgiu o [SubVersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) ou simplesmente SVN. Uma evolução em funcionalidade e confiabilidade em relação ao seu antecessor CVS.

#### CVS

Por isto a única coisa que vou dizer sobre o CVS é: não use, não perca tempo com ele. Ele não tem uma única simples vantagem em relação aos seus concorrentes.

#### O máximo da evolução

Ainda assim alguns projetos não eram bem atendidos por estes softwares. Daí surge uma nova geração de produtos que funcionam de forma distribuída, podendo trabalhar sem um servidor central (embora na prática acaba tendo um servidor final).

Isto não só possibilitou o trabalho de forma desconectada, interações mais complexas entre a equipe e viabilizou que equipes pudessem ter tamanho ilimitado, e também adicionou algumas facilidades, tornando o fluxo de trabalho mais organizado e flexível, permitindo hierarquias de repositórios, e especialmente para fazer *merge*, até porque isto passou ser uma demanda para equipes heterogêneas.

Alguns exemplos destes softwares surgidos neste século são: [Sun WorkShop TeamWare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_WorkShop_TeamWare), [Code Co-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Co-op), [BitKeeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitKeeper), [GNU arch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_arch) (o primeiro de código aberto), [Darcs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcs), [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Concurrent_Versions_System), [Monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_(software)), [Baazar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bazaar), [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)), [Mercurial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial), [Fossil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_(software)) (um pouco diferente dos seus concorrentes e que merece um olhar), [Veracity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veracity_(software)), [Plastic SCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_SCM). Estes últimos aproximando os dois modos [distribuído](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) e [centralizado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

Git e Mercurial começaram ser desenvolvidos para substituir o BitKeeper que teve uma mudança na licença. Eles acabaram se tornando os softwares de controle de versão distribuídos mais conhecidos. E mais recentemente com o crescimento da popularidade do [GitHub](https://github.com/) (repositório central *web* para o Git) ele se tornou dominante fazendo até mesmo Microsoft e Google preferirem seu uso em detrimento de seus próprios repositórios. A Microsoft acabou o comprando.

## Popularidade

Tirando os softwares proprietários como [Team Foundation Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) e alguns outros menos expressivos, poucos softwares mantiveram popularidade. Ainda há uma boa briga entre os dois modos de controlar versões. O SVN se tonou quase que o representante exclusivo para controle centralizado e o Git disparou na preferência para controle distribuído, seguido do Mercurial, cada vez com menos adeptos.

No fundo sobrou uma comparação a estes dois mais usados e de certa forma uma comparação entre os dois modos de controle, porque isto é o que mais os diferenciam.

Particularmente gosto mais dos sistemas mais simples (controle centralizado), embora admita que algumas funcionalidades dos sistemas mais complexos (distribuídos) são altamente desejáveis. Por isto gosto de soluções que tentam juntar ambos, então sempre me dei bem com SVN e Mercurial.

Mas também admito que fica cada vez mais complicado não olhar para o Git. Ter um repositório tão popular e ter cada vez mais boas integrações com outras ferramentas faz dele algo a se considerar mesmo que não precise um caminhão para entregar pizza.

Popularidade também é *feature*.

## SVN

Funciona muito bem para desenvolvedores individuais e pequenas equipes. Ele tem mecanismos mais práticos em fluxos de trabalho simples e que não costumam ter muito conflito. Ele brilha quando é exigido mais controle, principalmente em ambientes corporativos.

Se não consideramos a popularidade, o SVN **deveria** ser a primeira opção de desenvolvedores até que se perceba uma necessidade específica que só o Git pode trazer (e isto existe muito).

#### Vantagens

- É mais fácil de aprender e usar e se encaixa mais na intuição dos programadores.
- Se comporta mais como um controle de versão de arquivos em geral.
- Um único repositório canônico é mais adequado à filosofia corporativa permitindo maior controle e facilitando a administração.
- Permite trabalhar com partes dos repositório. Permite montar [*changesets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changeset).
- *Backup* é muito simples.
- Permite travar arquivos impedindo atualizações.
- Usa número de versão sequencial que simplifica navegar pelas versões.
- Controle de privilégios de acesso mais sofisticados.
- Mais fácil para trabalhar com arquivos binários, especialmente os grandes.
- Trabalha melhor com arquivos renomeados.
- Preserva o *timestamp* dos arquivos* (pelo menos em algumas situações).
- Dá mais liberdade na forma de trabalhar e organizar o projeto.
- *Branches* são apenas uma parte do repositório (para o bem ou para o mal).
- Como ele só trabalha com os arquivos, uma cópia inicial do repositório é relativamente rápida.
- Desincentiva fluxos de trabalho muitos complexos (sim, isto é uma vantagem).
- Está mais maduro, especialmente no Windows e utilização com GUI (era uma vantagem, hoje não mais, Giut melhorou demais nisso).

[Ver mais sobre alguns conceitos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20989/101) que estão fortemente arraigados no SVN.

#### SVK

É possível adotar um fluxo de trabalho mais descentralizado com SVN através do [SVK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVK). Pelo menos algumas das desvantagens do SVN podem ser mitigadas desta forma sem perder a maioria das vantagens. Pena ele não estar ativamente desenvolvido. Mas independente disto algumas pessoas desenvolvem fluxos parecidos.

## Git

Um sistema descentralizado brilha quando o desenvolvimento é descentralizado (ainda não entendo o uso individual mas [estou tentando entender](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43896/101)), especialmente em equipes grandes com grande quantidade de atualizações e fluxos complicados. Claro que ele pode ser usado em outros ambientes também.

Há uma grande curva de aprendizado. Tem uma filosofia mais próxima a dos sistemas baseados em UNIX cheio de ferramentas espalhadas e elas não são tão bem documentadas, elas não são pensadas para facilitar o trabalho e entendimento do que está sendo feito, não é muito intuitivo. (Cuidado, as pessoas que usam ele há muito tempo vão dizer que o SVN que não é intuitivo. Sim, quando você se acostuma com um modo de fazer, aquilo passa ser mais intuitivo para você. Depois que se acostuma com um trabalho ele se torna intuitivo).

Uma diferença importante é que em sistemas distribuídos há uma distinção entre *commit* e *push*. O *commit* cria um [*snapshot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_%28computer_storage%29) local e só o *push* realmente manda as revisões pendentes para outro repositório (possivelmente remoto). Em sistemas centralizados o *commit* faz tudo. Isto é mais simples mas cria dificuldades em ambientes de muitas atualizações por usuários diferentes.

#### Vantagens

- Controla conteúdos de forma mais geral.
- Em quase tudo é executado mais rápido, em alguns casos absurdamente mais rápido. Ele é otimizado para funcionar pela internet.
- O repositório ocupa menos espaço. E é mais fácil repará-lo.
- É muito mais fácil administrar diversas fontes de atualizações.
- É fácil trabalhar com cópias locais para fazer experimentos e desenvolvimentos paralelos. *Branches* são baratos e simples. São até incentivados.
- Incentiva o *commit* frequente.
- Facilita muito fazer *merge*.
- Permite trabalhar confortavelmente sem perder nenhuma funcionalidade e informação sem estar conectado ao servidor central (que pode e frequentemente é usado). Ele tem mais metadados locais.
- Possui mais informações de auditoria e que permitem mais facilidades em toda a administração.
- Manipula conversão de fim de linha mais facilmente.
- As revisões são assinadas digitalmente.
- A história do projeto pode ser modificada.
- Possui uma *staging area* que permite selecionar partes que deseja enviar para um repositório.
- Permite uma gama maior de fluxos de trabalho.

Algumas dessas vantagens estão disponíveis hoje também no SVN.

## Sobre repositórios centralizados não escalar bem

Isto não é bem verdade, como sempre digo, depende de quem faz. [A Google fez funcionar bem um único repositório para **toda sua base de código**](https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2016/7/204032-why-google-stores-billions-of-lines-of-code-in-a-single-repository/fulltext) e é uma das maiores do mundo, absurdamente maior que do Linux que se entende que centralizado não funcionaria (claro que são objetivos diferentes).

Também sempre digo que existe uma diferença entre bons programadores e bons engenheiros. Quem sabe fazer engenharia sempre acha soluções melhores. Quem não é engenheiro, e nenhum mal nisso, faz o que todo mundo está fazendo, às vezes pensando um pouco, às vezes sem pensar. E não me entenda errado, essas pessoas são boas em programação, entendem razoavelmente o que estão fazendo, mas procuram a solução pronta e não a melhor solução. Apesar de ter seu mérito, isto não é engenharia.

O Git é ótimo, mas eu só o uso porque é mais fácil usar o que todo mundo está usando. Se fosse para escolher um controle de versão descentralizado seria o Mercurial, mas um centralizado costuma me atender melhor. Cada um deve procurar o que melhor lhe atende.

## Conclusão

Esta análise pode ficar defasada porque os dois softwares tentam se aproximar mais do outro e melhorar em suas deficiências (de fato isto vem acontecendo desde que escrevi a versão original)). Não existe milagre, a única forma de saber ao certo se o software é bom para você, é instalar e começar usar.

Dada a popularidade o Git acabou dominando a indústria. Ainda existirem motivos para usar outras coisas, mas se eles não forma fortes o Git acaba sendo a escolha mais fácil.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).