# Como usar um objeto para adicionar a um atributo?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Quando faço o código a baixo recebe esse erro:

> Object of class Cliente could not be converted to string in ...\animal.class.php

Nessa parte não me permite passar um objeto para ser usado na propriedade "dono"

```
$dog = new Cachorro('Rex',$ana);
```

Porém quando uso *string* 'ana' ex.:

```
$dog = new Cachorro('Rex','ana');
```

funciona normalmente e me retorna o "ana" como dona do animal

```
//classe Cliente
class Cliente{
    public $nome;

public function __construct($nome){
        $this->nome     = $nome;
    }
}

abstract Animal{
    protected $nome;
    protected $dono;

   public function __construct($nome,$dono){
       $this->nome      = $nome;
       $this->dono  = $dono;
   }

  public function getDono(){
        return $this->dono ;
    }
}
//Essa classe foi implementada, porém nada está afetando e a deixei "isolei" para ter   certeza
class Cachorro extends Animal{

}

$ana = new Cliente('ana');
$dog = new Cachorro('Rex','ana' );
echo "Dono: ". $dog->getDono();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vou responder já que você tem respostas divergentes e não sabe o que fazer.

Você já aprendeu nas outras respostas que há um problema de compatibilidade de tipo. Em condições normais você não pode imprimir o conteúdo de um tipo complexo, em geral que você criou. nenhum componente sabe como imprimir este conjunto de dados. Você, o criador do tipo precisa "ensinar" a aplicação de como fazer isto. Você está sempre preocupado em fazer o certo e isto é o certo. Toda classe deve se responsabilizar por tudo o que se refere à ela.

Então criar o método `__tostring()`, conforme definiu a resposta do sergiopereira, não só é útil, é quase obrigatório. De fato algumas linguagens de programação obrigam mesmo. Ou pelo menos fornecem um método padrão para fazer isto para todas as classes (a forma de fazer isto varia dependendo da filosofia da linguagem).

De fato o Guilherme Nascimento está certo em chamar este método de mágico mas não tem nenhum problema em usá-lo. O construtor também é mágico. Não há e não deveria mesmo nenhuma regra para evitar seu uso. Pelo contrário, estes são métodos desejáveis em determinadas situações.

Você gosta de fazer o certo. Então se pergunte: quando você construir uma instância de `Cachorro` você quer dizer que ela esteja associada a um **dono** ou ao um **nome de dono**? Parece que sua intenção inicial era usa a primeira forma. E acho que é melhor mesmo. Não está errado colocar apenas um nome de dono no cachorro se você desejar mas eu acho que cachorros tem donos por completo. Como passar o nome você tem apenas o nome, não associa realmente ao dono. Na maioria das situações não é o que você precisa. Eu descartaria qualquer solução em cima do nome.

Então a solução inicial sua estava correta. O erro estava em acessar o dono. Você tentou imprimir o dono e a aplicação não sabia como.

Se sua intenção era imprimir explicitamente o nome do dono, então deveria pedir para imprimir o nome do dono e não para imprimir o dono. Pode parecer bobagem mas conceituar as coisas corretamente em programação é fundamental. Se você não define com precisão o que quer fazer, não conseguirá expressar em código corretamente.

Então as duas respostas estão corretas, elas só não explicaram para você quando e porque usar cada uma. Eu usaria as duas.

```
class Cliente {
    private $nome;
    public function __construct($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }
    public function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->nome;
    }
}
abstract class Animal {
    protected $nome;
    protected $dono;
    public function __construct($nome, $dono) {
       $this->nome = $nome;
       $this->dono = $dono;
   }
    public function getDono() {
        return $this->dono;
    }
}
class Cachorro extends Animal {
    public function __construct($nome, $dono) {
       parent::__construct($nome, $dono);
   }
}
$ana = new Cliente('ana');
$dog = new Cachorro('Rex', $ana);
echo "Dono: " . $dog->getDono();
echo "\nNome do dono: " . $dog->getDono()->getNome();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dAQC91). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/isjiaebe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/GetterNested.php).

Note que eu mandei imprimir o dono e o nome do dono. Por acaso o resultado é o mesmo, mas tome como um mero acaso. No futuro cada técnica poderá dar resultados diferentes.

---

Como você quer aprender vou aproveitar para te dizer para evitar comentários óbvio como dizer que a classe é `Cliente` é a classe `Cliente`. Viu como é óbvio? [Comentários devem dizer porque e não o que](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15566/101).

Também procure manter o código com organização consistente. Pode parecer bobagem mas é fundamental fazer isto. Você visualiza melhor. As pessoas que vão trabalhar com seu código, inclusive aqui visualizam melhor. Você começa organizar seus pensamentos de forma mais organizada.

Estou dizendo isso porque não parece ser o seu caso mas tem programadores iniciantes que são teimosos, que acham que isto é bobagem. E eles passam a vida toda fazendo tudo errado e nunca aprendem a fazer código de qualidade. Nunca conheci nos meus mais de 30 anos de experiência um só programador bom que não se preocupasse com estes detalhes. Inclusive tem quem defenda que o *site* deveria atender os usuários de qualquer jeito, sem organização. Estas pessoas não entendem que estão prestando um desserviço aos usuários. Não estão ajudando os programadores a evoluir como é necessário. Originalmente o objetivo da rede de *sites* da StackExchange era fazer todos aprenderem, ser diferente dos fóruns que só davam soluções. E aí os programadores ficam assim como o último gráfico [dessa página](https://github.com/Dobiasd/articles/blob/master/programming_language_learning_curves.md) (segundo minha experiência os gráficos me parecem bastante próximos da realidade na maioria dos casos).

[Não sou fã do termo atributo, prefiro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Comment: Bom dia @bigown Eu não expliquei sobre _tostring por que isto não está na pergunta e eu não disse que é um método mágico me referindo como se fosse algo errado, só que pelo código dele, me parece que ele está "aprendendo" sobre orientação a objetos , portanto a minha resposta cobre inteiramente a pergunta e se faz a mais correta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento concordo, inclusive não disse que a sua resposta estava errada. Só que dizer que a sua resposta é a **mais correta** é forçação de barra. Eu não acho que seja, mesmo ela estando perfeitamente correta ela induz ao uso do nome do dono e não dá uma alternativa ao que ele está tentando fazer. Reafirmo que isto não é problema mas não deixa de ser uma resposta que não expõe tudo o que poderia. Mas se está tentando dizer para o AP que ele deve aceitar a sua resposta, isto será decisão dele depois da análise dele, não cabe a você decidir por ele.

Comment: Não é isso bigown, eu não disse que ele é obrigado a aceitar a minha resposta; Não acho que seja **forçar barra** por que eu expliquei sobre um uso na orientação a objeto; Não vejo o por que `__toString()` deveria ser parte da minha resposta e ou explicar sobre isto, sendo que não é o foco da questão dele.

Comment: obrigado  a todos que me ajudaram, por mais que eu não tenha marcado a resposta de vcs, mas me ajudaram bastante !!

Comment: @bigown obrigado pela sugestão, vc tem algum material para que eu possa aprender a manter o código mais organizado e consistente ?

Comment: @LeandroMacedo não tenho nada específico, pode começar por aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/estilo-de-codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o. Mas estou falando até mesmo de coisas básicas como indentar blocos, dar espaçamento que facilite a visualização. Mas o motivo de eu ter falado é que lhe falta consistência, ou seja, cada momento você faz de um jeito. Sua preocupação é só se executa ou não. Analise caractere por caractere do seu código e veja como tem diferenças. Não prejudica o código fortemente mas cria um padrão de descompromisso. Só falo isto porque percebo que você quer o melhor.

Answer (score 8):

Você está adicionando um `Object` (classe Cliente) a variavel `$ana`

```
$ana = new Cliente('ana');
```

Portanto aqui `$this->dono = $dono;` recebe um objeto (e não uma `string`)

```
public function __construct($nome,$dono){
   $this->nome  = $nome;
   $this->dono  = $dono;
}
```

No momento que você tentar imprimir com `echo` o metodo `getDono()` ele vai enviar a variavel `$this->dono` que anteriormente você setou como a "classe Ana" (um objeto)

```
public function getDono(){
    return $this->dono; //Retorna o objeto
}
```

O correto seria assim:

```
echo "Dono: ". $dog->getDono()->nome;
```

Ou assim:

```
$ana = new Cliente('ana');
$dog = new Cachorro('Rex', $ana->nome);
echo "Dono: ". $dog->getDono();
```

Você também pode tornar a variável nome em `private` (ou `protected`) e criar um método para pegar ela, assim prevenindo que acidentalmente alguém sete um valor para ela fora da classe:

```
class Cliente {
    private $nome;

    public function __construct($nome){
        $this->nome     = $nome;
    }

    public function getNome(){
        return $this->nome;
    }
}
```

e usar desta maneira:

```
$ana = new Cliente('ana');
$dog = new Cachorro('Rex', $ana->getNome());
echo "Dono: ". $dog->getDono();
```

Comment: nossa funcionou como eu desejava, porém agora fiquei na dúvida qual a forma correta e mais aconselhável, se a sua ou do @sergiopereira (resposta de cima) ? não que eu esteja te menosprezando

Comment: @LeandroMacedo a resposta do sergio é apenas um método "mágico", eu discordo do Sérgio, por que existem maneiras melhores e mais fáceis de quem for usar a classe, o melhor é trabalhar com um metodo `get` (ex: `public function getNome() { return $this->nome; }`) (na minha opinião). Eu pessoalmente acho a minha resposta mais correta.

Answer (score 6):

Tente adicionar um método `__toString` à sua classe `Cliente`, tipo:

```
public function __toString() {
    return $this->nome;
}
```

Assim você poderá passar `$ana` no lugar de `'ana'` sem problemas:

```
$ana = new Cliente('ana');
$dog = new Cachorro('Rex', $ana);
echo "Dono: ". $dog->getDono();
```

Comment: ok, funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!! essa é a melhor maneira ou á apresentada pelo @Guilherme Ferreira (resposta de baixo) é a ideal ?

Comment: Eu acho essa maneira a mais útil mas depende muito de como você quer usar os objetos `Cliente` na sua aplicação. No seu problema original você quer concatenar uma string (`"Dono: "`) com um objeto `Cliente`. O que você desejava que fosse o resultado? Aparecer o nome do dono? A palavra `"Cliente"`? O PHP não tem como adivinhar o resultado esperado, assim você pode ser mais explícito como `$dog->getDono()->getNome()` ou usar `__toString()` como um atalho. O `__toString()` ainda pode ajudar mais tarde, quando você estiver debugando algo. Eu diria que é uma boa prática.

Comment: eu esperava receber o nome do  "dono"