# O objetivo da herança é o reúso?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, herança

Muitos falam que o objetivo da herança em orientação a objetos é promover o reúso do código, mas acredito que isso é um engano.

Lembro (ou penso) ter lido que o objetivo NÃO é o reúso mas não lembro agora do que se tratava.

Pelo menos não é o objetivo principal.

Em primeiro lugar as classes têm que satisfazer o princípio de substituição de Liskov. Além disso, a herança (digamos, a generalização) gera uma abstração, que permite trabalhar num nível mais alto de código.

Em terceiro lugar viria o reúso.

Estou deixando de enxergar alguma coisa?

Comment: Acredito que polimorfismo seja o maior motivo legítimo para criar uma hierarquia de classes.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11594/%c3%89-errado-usar-heran%c3%a7a-de-classes-para-agrupar-comportamentos-e-atributos-comuns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É o que eu falo sempre, [orientação a objeto é mal definido e depende de quem define](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101) ([veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276787/101)).

Vai encontrar sim que herança é para reúso em vários locais e não estou falando de fontes aleatórias da internet.

A herança que usamos na prática parte de duas coisas: [a herança de subtipo e a herança de implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101) ([também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190140/o-que-%C3%A9-heran%C3%A7a-de-tipo-e-estado/190146?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C24.7656#190146)).

A parte do subtipo tem a ver com os [contratos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51210/101). Em geral falamos dos contratos explícitos que são as [assinaturas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) que vemos no código, mas o resultado (semântico) que se espera não deixa de ser um contrato. Tudo isso tem a ver com Liskov. Esse princípio diz que o tipo filho deve fazer tudo o que o tipo pai faz. O detalhe pode até mudar, mas a forma de usar e o resultado não pode.

A [abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23103/101) é dizer o que o tipo fará em termos gerais, dar uma base do que precisa ser entregue sem dar todos detalhes que serão dados de forma especializada. Ela pode dar implementação que será reusada.

Quando você estende uma classe está **reusando** o que já tem lá para fazer algo um pouco mais especializado.

A parte da implementação é o tal do reúso. Sem ser para reúso não faz sentido haver herança, a não ser que queira só o subtipo. Algumas pessoas acham que isso é secundário e talvez por esse motivo pregam que ele não é o objetivo.

Se a herança ocorre só no subtipo então usar interface em uma classe é herança? Há controvérsias. Interface é só contrato, não tem implementação (andaram deturpando isso, mas dentro da normalidade). Se é herança por que as linguagens usam `implements` e não `inherits` quando a usa?

Linguagem de tipagem dinâmica não liga tanto para contratos, portanto não liga tanto para a conformidade do subtipo. Então linguagens de tipagem dinâmica não tem herança?

Pode-se dizer que não é o principal, mas não dá para dizer que o reúso não é um objetivo.

Ao mesmo tempo o reúso pode ser obtido com [outras formas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136913/101) que não a herança.

[Você não consegue forçar Liskov totalmente pelo código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101), mas o que dá pode fazer só com interface.

[Para criar uma abstração pode usar a interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89275/101).

Se tirar o reúso da equação a interface é suficiente para definir herança. Algumas pessoas acham isso mesmo e dizem que só deveria existir interface. As pessoas podem achar o que quiserem, mas tem justificativa válida?

Algumas pessoas dizem que para reúso deveria importar uma implementação privativamente, deveria ser descolada do subtipo, em geral por [*mixin*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42970/101) ([também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/275897/101)) ou algum mecanismo que produz o mesmo efeito. Mas por que não pode ter as duas coisas? A maioria das linguagens OO discordam dessas pessoas e fazem as duas coisas.

Se você tira o reúso, a herança como é comumente usada, deixa de existir por completo e parte-se para a [composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101) ou [delegação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87524/101) como mecanismo de reúso. Tem caso que deve ser realmente assim, e [vivo defendendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/263289/101), mas tem caso para herança, reusando o que já existe.

Só é preciso cuidado porque as pessoas abusam e enxergam reúso por herança, generalização onde não existe. Um exemplo que sempre cito é que [`Cliente` ou `Aluno` não é especialização de `Pessoa`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101). Esse é o reúso errado, e que "todo mundo" que defende pureza de OO, que diz que não herança não é sobre reúso, erram justamente por praticar reúso por herança onde não deve, o certo ali é a composição.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).