# Diferenças de retorno booleano

Tags: php, if, estilo-de-codificação, booleano

Me deparei com o seguinte exemplo:

```
$umidade = 91;

$vai_chover = ($umidade > 90);

if ($vai_chover) { echo "vai chover"; }
```

A `$vai_chover` retorna um booleano no `if`, porém achei muito código para fazer pouca coisa, não seria a mesma coisa se ela fosse escrita assim:

```
$umidade = 91;

if ($umidade > 89) { echo "vai chover"; }
```

Teoricamente o `if` faz o mesmo teste, o que muda só que ele não esta armazenado numa variável.

Em que casos usamos um ou outro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para entender melhor deve ler [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

Sabendo o que é uma variável a pergunta a ser feita é se precisa armazenar o seu valor em algum lugar. Qual o motivo de armazenar o valor em uma variável e depois usá-la apenas uma vez?

Parece que nenhuma, certo? Eu concordo com isso e de forma geral não vejo vantagem em fazer dessa forma.

Porém existe uma "escola" (no sentido de grupo que segue determinadas formas de fazer) que prega a legibilidade do código acima de qualquer outra coisa. E eles tem certa razão. Você escreve o código apenas uma vez e lê diversas, inclusive é comum que pessoas que não o escreveram leiam diversas vezes. Quanto melhor documentar o que está fazendo e deixando óbvio o que significa aquilo, melhor o código é.

Uma das formas de fazer isso é colocar muito comentário para dizer que está acontecendo. Mas comentário viola o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e você acaba tendo duas informações sobre a mesma coisa, então toda vez que mexer em algo no código tem que lembrar de mexer no comentário, se não fizer você tem o pior dos dois mundos, um comentário que diz que o código faz algo que ele não faz.

Veja mais sobre isso em:

- [O que são comentários WET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/363051/101)
- [Como saber a medida certa de comentários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15488/101)
- [Comentários em código ao trabalhar em grupo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56751/101)
- [Existe uma forma correta de comentar um trecho de código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153813/101)
- [O que é uma documentação formal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/428506/101)
- [Recomendações para comentários em uma interface e seus contratos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51210/101)

E também [Como escrever um código legível e de fácil manutenção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/101).

Então como documentar de forma legível o que é aquilo e não parecer uma [expressão mágica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101) sem usar comentários?

Fácil, crie um código descritivo do que é aquilo. A forma simples de fazer isso é criar um identificador para aquilo. Esse identificador pode ser uma função ou uma variável.

Se fizer uma função ela poderá ser usada em vários outros pontos do código e será bem DRY. Se optar pela variável pode usar de novo ali mesmo naquele trecho, mas não fora da função atual, e será DRY se houver repetir.

Eu respondi isso em [Atribuir uma expressão a uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44741/101) e ["if" elegante em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/427782/101) e também ["== true" é útil para alguma coisa? É melhor "!" ou "== false"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/315434/101).

Mas se eu só vou usar uma vez não seria redundante? Não, não é, tem um motivo para isso, não muda nada na execução, mas documenta melhor de forma canônica. É bom, deixa de ter magia, o código está explicando que vai chover, não é só uma análise de um número que nada indica o que é aquilo.

Então você deve ter pego um código ou explicação de alguém que segue a escola da boa documentação, do explícito melhor que o implícito (que me lembra de Python que tem isso em sua filosofia básica e quase ninguém segue, principalmente os novos usuários dessa linguagem que não ligam a mínima pra programação).

Você quer seguir essa escola? Alguns não querem. Mas sabem porque não querem. Uma decisão avaliada, justificada é uma boa decisão. Você sabe porque não seguirá isso. Qualquer decisão sem pensar bem é uma má decisão.

Talvez o caminho seja o meio termo, seja pensar bem o que está fazendo e fazer mais legível quando é necessário, quando não é bastante óbvio mesmo sem um nome identificador.

Você precisa achar seu jeito. Ou seguir o jeito da sua equipe. O mais importante é pensar sobre todo código que cria, e isso poucas pessoas fazem. Cada código que coloca deve ser justificado, e se deixa de colocar algo que poderia ter escrito tem que ser justificado.

Costumo colocar isso nas minhas palestras:

[image: Enquanto você não souber o que cada caractere do seu código faz, até mesmo o espaço em branco, você ainda não sabe programar]

E as pessoas não entendem que o código deve refletir o que é definido fora dele. Parece óbvio, mas não é. Se fosse, todo mundo seguiria isso muito bem. As pessoas tendem achar que estão seguindo, mesmo não sendo verdade.

Então seu problema precisa de uma definição clara que a umidade maior que 90 é quando chove? Ou só precisa saber que essa quantidade de umidade deve fazer algo?

Nesse código em específico eu diria de cara que a variável não é necessária porque a ação seguinte já indica o que é aquilo. Mas isso só ocorre porque o código é artificial.

Eu costumo dizer que você pode aprender um mecanismo com um código artificial, mas só aprende programar com códigos reais. Esse não ensina o jeito certo de fazer porque ele é todo redundante.

Sim, todo, porque nem o `if` precisa nesse código. Você já sabe o valor antes então não tem porque comparar algo.

Esse código pode demonstrar o uso de uma variável como forma de documentação, mas não pode ensinar quando usar essa técnica, porque esse caso ele é inadequado.

Como exemplo do mecanismo ele serve, não estou reclamando disso, mas não ensina como deve ser uma codificação real, só precisa ter isso muito claro, a maioria não tem, elas começam copiar sem pensar.

Em paralelo, se acha que algo redundante não deve ser usado, então por que usou chaves? Elas são redundantes nesse caso. Há parênteses que também o são no primero exemplo.

Tem o outro ponto que eu percebi na pergunta: o título fala em retorno. Isso significa que a função ainda retorna um valor? Esse valor é se choveu ou não? Então a variável seria usada novamente? Aí faz muito sentido existir. Se não retorna nada, por que tem isso no título? Seria um título mal definido? Se um problema é mal definido a solução sempre estará errada, mesmo que ela funcione.

isso deve estar em uma função, qual o nome da função? Será que ela já não documenta bem o que faz? Se o nome dela é muito descritivo e ela é bem simples, como parece, então pode ser que não precisa descrever mais ainda.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

## Conclusão

Não é muita coisa, é só um nome de variável a mais. Documentar bem não é pouca coisa. Se acha que isso não importa experimente colocar todas variáveis que são obrigatórias apenas com uma letra, ou usar palavrões em vez de nomes significativos (já vi fazerem isso).

Em algumas linguagens criar uma variável pode ter um custo de performance em certas situações, então é algo para se pensar se precisa do máximo da performance, o que não é o caso quando se opta por PHP.

Não tem uma resposta única.

Aprender a tecnologia pouco importa. Desenvolver software é apego ao detalhe. É um pouco uma arte que o bom senso e bom gosto conta, sem deixar a exatidão que a solução exige. É fundamentação. É comprometimento. É questionar tudo, por isso também uso nas minhas palestras:

[image: Aquele que não questiona tende a aceitar e a se sujeitar à ideia alheia...]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -3):

Não há nenhuma diferença entre os dois exemplos além do valor que você colocou depois do operador de comparação.É como você disse, o primeiro exemplo é muito código para pouca coisa.