# Ler documentação XML gerada pelo Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, documentação

Como posso ler a documentação XML gerada pelo Visual Studio de alguma forma que fique formatado?

Comment: Não é só abrir com um editor de texto?

Comment: Sim, mas vc abre o XML, gostaria de abrir ele em forma de documento, help e se possível formatado e não com as tags XML.

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

[O Visual Studio consegue usar isto diretamente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/msgulfcommunity/creating-documentation-in-c-using-visual-studio-and-sandcastle?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (na verdade [é preciso só o compilador](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/doc-compiler-option?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)), mas se quer algo externo que faça algo mais sofisticado:

- [GhostDoc](https://submain.com/ghostdoc/) - bastante popular e fácil de usar
- [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) - muito completo e funciona bem para outras linguagens
- [SandCastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) - (era, não sei se ainda é verdade) o mais popular, bem complexo, precisa de *plugins*, chega ser [quase oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [Docu](http://docu.jagregory.com/)
- [Natural Docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/)
- [MonoDoc](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/monodoc/)
- [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/)

Eu ficaria com um dos 3 primeiros. Preferi omitir os pagos. Avalie qual deles é melhor para a sua necessidade.

[Outras opções](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators).

Answer (score 2):

Eu recomendo o [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org). Alguns exemplos de documentação do doxygen:

- [Precog Client](http://precog.com/apidocs/dotnet/index.html) (bem simples)
- [Craig's Utility Library](https://github.com/JaCraig/Craig-s-Utility-Library) (mais completo)

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo [Sandcastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) tambem. Tem muita flexibilidade e varias transfomacoes (.chm, .hxs, .xmshc)...embora nao cria paginas atuais de 'wiki'.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, o [Sandcastle](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10526).

Há ainda o [NDOC](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/) e o [DocProject](http://www.codeplex.com/DocProject) que podem ser úteis.