# TODO - O que é, qual sua utilidade e como usar?

Tags: terminologia, ide, comentários

Já vi bastante essa palavra **"TODO"**, principalmente em IDE's e sempre tive a curiosidade de saber o que é.

**Exemplo:**

```
// TODO: alguma coisa escrita
código....
```

Agora as perguntas:

- O que é TODO?
- Qual sua utilidade?
- Como usar?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Você viu isso em código, pode ser chamado de *code tags*.

Estritamente é um comentário como outro qualquer. Ele pode ter um significado específico para alguma ferramenta. É comum IDEs ou pelo menos extensões deles terem alguma coisa que vasculham o código procurando comentários que começam com:

- `TODO:` ("para fazer") Alguém [eu] precisa arrumar isso urgente
- `FIXME:` ("me conserte") Tem um erro que precisa ser consertado aqui, mas funciona (`TOFIX:`)
- `HACK:` ("gambi") Não teve outro jeito de resolver pra cumprir o prazo, depois melhoro
- `XXX:` ("atenção") Alguns editores destacam comentários com isto como algo importante sem dar semântica específica
- `DONE:` ("feito") Avisar que o `TODO` está resolvido. Quando remover isto?
- `UNDONE:` ("desfeito") Precisei voltar ao original por alguma razão
- `ASAP:` ("tão rápido quanto possível") Precisa arrumar isso urgente
- `REMOVE:` ("remova") Esse código foi colocado só para testar algo e deve sumir
- `NOTE:` ("anotação") Só para informar que tem algo importante agora
- `BUG:` ("falha") Tem um bug conhecido aqui que precisa ser arrumado - especialização do FIXME - costuma ter um número de ticket associado
- `ISSUE:` ("questão") Há uma dúvida aqui se deve ser assim mesmo
- `ERROR:` ("erro") Tem um erro reproduzível aqui - especialização do FIXME
- `BROKEN:` ("quebrado") não vai pra frente mesmo, não adianta insistir - especialização do FIXME
- `GLITCH` ("falha") Algo estranho ocorre aqui em situação bem específica
- `REVIEW:` ("revise") Revise isso pra mim, usado onde se costuma fazer *peer review*
- `WTF:` ("que p0rr@ é essa?") Fizeram um besteira muito grande aqui

E outras parecidas...

As ferramentas catalogam esses comentários em algum lugar específico, não fica só no código para destacar que o código não está completo ou pelo menos precisa de atenção especial para os programadores não ignorarem por acidente.

Muitos permitem configurar o que quiser, mas se exagerar pode começar dificultar o uso, em geral os 3 primeiros são bem úteis (para o VIM só o quarto é considerado), os outros são variações, especializações, exageros ou exigem ferramentas melhores.

Em geral há uma descrição mais detalhada depois dos dois pontos. Esta *tag* específica serve para ajudar a ferramenta identificar a semântica deste comentário.

Essa é uma prática de programadores organizados. É claro que se enfiar um monte deles e largar dá no mesmo que não usar. Em geral eles devem ser transitórios.

Algumas equipes até proíbem que código com isso seja *commitado*, a não ser nos casos que sejam para comunicação com outros membros da equipe. O argumento é que se é uma coisa planejada e não implementada deve ficar na documentação, se é algo que falta fazer pra cumprir a implementação planejada então o *commit* não pode ser feito até completar. A realidade impede que o fluxo seja de fato assim, o máximo que acontece é as pessoas tirarem isso do código e marcar em outro lugar mais fácil de esquecer, só para burlar a regra boba.

Alguém lembra de outros?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sempre vi esse TODO nos códigos, mas pensei que não fosse um comentário gerado pela IDE sem importância kkk.

Comment: Não é gerado pelo IDE, é colocado pelo programador, o IDE só o usa pra produzir um catálogo.

Answer (score 11):

Esse termo pode-se traduzir de forma literal.

Significa “a fazer”, “para fazer”.

Não é algo específico de linguagens de programação. É meramente um lembrete de coisas a se fazer, normalmente uma correção ou implementação relevante que o programador resolveu deixar para fazer em outra ocasião.