# O que são "Números Mágicos"?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, números-mágicos

A minha IDE informou que estou utilizando **números mágicos** em meu código, 
no trecho `f = 12`.

Gostaria de saber melhor o que são "números mágicos". 
Preciso ter uma variável com valor 12, mas a IDE falou algo sobre constantes em JavaScript.

Devo me preocupar com esses *magic numbers* a longo prazo?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Definição do termo

Na verdade isso vale pra qualquer linguagem. São [números sem significado claro](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicNumber), números que parecem terem sido tirados da cartola.

Partindo do princípio que uma variável é apenas um nome para um valor, os números mágicos apenas são números "constantes" sem nome. Quando damos um nome pra eles, eles deixam de ser mágicos. Em geral preferimos que eles sejam colocados em constantes. Nada impede que sejam variáveis que não devem variar de fato durante a execução. Há linguagens que usam substituição de texto apenas (troca o nome pelo número).

Pelo menos essa é uma das definições do termo. No contexto apresentado é isso.

## IDE agindo

Claro que para um IDE é difícil afirmar isso, depende de contexto. Esse específico que está usando acha que não pode ter algo assim. Deve ter uma regra de "boa prática" ligada nele pra te obrigar fazer tudo do jeito que ele acha certo.

## Validade da técnica

Tem casos que é bom mesmo criar uma constante e usá-la. Documenta melhor a intenção daquele número (dá mais semântica), afinal [comentários devem ser evitados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15566/101) de qualquer forma, e principalmente alcança o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), ou seja, colocar em um só lugar a informação de forma canônica, assim uma mudança necessária exigiria a troca de um só lugar pra refletir em todos e evitar desbalancear a aplicação.

Veja exemplos nas outras respostas de como isso pode ser necessário. Outro:

```
const maxLenghtPassword = 8;
...
if (texto.Lenght < maxLenghtPassword) { //melhor que por o 8 aqui, já que ele pode mudar
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/MagicNumber.ptg).

Tem número que não é tão mágico assim e até faz sentido usar naturalmente. Isso ocorre muito com o 0 (claro que o problema é mais de contexto e não do algarismo em si). O zero muitas vezes é usado como limite baixo de alguma coisa e nunca vai mudar. O mesmo vale para o 1 e até -1. Mas aí depende de como a pessoa gosta de trabalhar.

Você usaria o 7 como número de dias da semana (nunca muda) ou criaria uma constante, sei lá, `const DaysInAWeek = 7` para representar isso e usar a constante sempre que precisa desta informação? Seja o que for, seja consistente.

Todo mundo sabe o valor de PI e ele é constante sempre, nunca vai mudar. Essa constante existe. Claro que no caso dele é algo que nem todos vão se lembrar. E mesmo que uma pessoa veja um `3.14159` e saiba do que se trata, fica mais documentado que a intenção é usar PI. Por esse mesmo motivo alguém usaria `DaysInAWeek`.

Então tem quem ache que tudo deveria ser constante e nada deveria ser número direto. Eu gosto das constantes, mas não exagero, tudo depende do caso. Tem que tomar cuidado para não criar obviedades, algo como `const abreParentese = "("` (não precisa ser número mesmo). Há ganho em fazer isto? Pode até ser em algum caso, mas duvido. Há ganho em fazer `const zero = 0`?. Não é para descrever o conteúdo da variável, e sim para dar significado a ele. Eu acho que não fica bom assim.

Tem a desvantagem de que se você quiser saber o número concreto mesmo, tem que procurar por ele. Alguns IDEs conseguem lhe mostrar com facilidade, mas não está lá no texto.

No passado recomendava-se declarar tudo em maiúsculo para diferenciar. Hoje isso faz menos sentido, mas depende de linguagem. Hoje um IDE pode destacar que é uma constante e não uma variável.

## Performance e consumo de memória

Em algumas linguagens isso pode ser feito sem ocupar nada de espaço de variável e sem causar [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), fica tudo resolvido em tempo de compilação e o artifício fica restrito para melhor legibilidade do código. Tem linguagem que causa custos para o código, mas nada exagerado.

## Textos mágicos

Claro que não precisa ser só números, podem ser textos, ou mesmo outras coisas que existam literais para eles e possam ser criados em tempo de compilação.

Answer (score 14):

Números Mágicos, são números espalhados em blocos de códigos os dois grandes problemas são pouca semântica(informação sobre o uso) e a possibilidade desse número estar espalhado por N linhas, o que significa N alterações em lugares diferentes.

A solução é transformar esse número em uma 'refêrencia' pode ser transformar ele em um constante ou variável e/ou ainda criar um ponto unico de alteração (criação de um método para a atividade).

Exemplo de número mágico

```
var intD = 86400 * 30
```

Possível solução

```
var segundosDeUmDia = 86400;
var outroValor = 30;
var total = segundosDeUmDia * outroValor;
```

Comment: Porque não `var total=...` @rray?

Comment: @Miguel pq eu esqueci do var hahaha xD

Comment: ha lol, pensei que tinha a ver com o problema

Answer (score 13):

Imagine que você pegou um programa para dar manutenção e vê a seguinte linha:

```
if (meuCodigo == 12) {
   varX = 2;
}
```

Você saberia me dizer o que está acontecendo?

Claro que não, pois você teria que procurar em todo o código até achar o que significam estes números.

Se você definir `constantes`:

```
const EXPORTACAO = 12;
const PREMIUM = 2;

if (meuCodigo == TIPO_EXPORTACAO) {
   varX = PREMIUM;
}
```

A coisa fica muito mais simples.

Obs: Tem um vídeo bem legal do Rafael Ponte sobre isso aqui [Dica #2 - Números Mágicos](http://dicas.triadworks.com.br/dica-2-numeros-magicos/)