# Variável static e #define

Tags: c, variáveis, declaração-de-variável, static, diretivas-de-compilação

Qual é a diferença entre definir uma variável `static` e usar o `#define` no C? Aparentemente os dois tem a mesma função, certo?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 8):

`#define` na verdade nem faz parte da linguagem. É só um texto que antes da compilação será trocado por um valor. Parece uma variável, mas não é. O valor é que será usado. Obviamente ele não pode ser trocado.

Normalmente é usado para [evitar números mágicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101), pelo menos nesse contexto.

Uma variável estática realmente é um local de armazenamento do código. Ela pode ser alterada. Ela existirá durante toda a execução da aplicação, não importa onde ela tenha sido declarada. O local de declaração dela define o escopo, a visibilidade da variável, mas não o tempo de vida.

Então se ela estiver dentro de uma função, ela existirá em todas as chamadas. Seu valor permanecerá entre uma chamada e outra. Isso pode ser um perigo em aplicações com acesso concorrente.

Se for em um arquivo, ela terá a mesma característica e poderá ser acessada em todo o arquivo.

Se ela for declarada global (não recomendo) ela poderá ser acessado em qualquer lugar.

Esse exemplo pode ajudar entender:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define constante 0

void funcao() {
    int variavel = constante; // se colocasse 0 aqui daria na mesma
    static int estatica = constante;
    variavel++;
    estatica++;
    printf("variavel = %d, estatica = %d\n", variavel, estatica);
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) funcao();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DFL7nF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gzlujltc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Static.c).

Veja [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101)

Answer (score 1):

`#define` é um commando de pre-compilação, essas instruções são executadas antes da compilação propriamente dita e qualquer valor definido não poderá ser alterado no decorrer do codigo.

variáveis `statics` por outro lado podem sofre alterações, no entanto seu valor é resguardado além das fronteiras nas quais a variável foi definida.