# Como funciona o tempo de vida de variáveis estáticas?

Tags: c, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis, variável-estática, tempo-de-vida

Vi há pouco uma pergunta sobre C. Nela o seguinte código era mostrado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    static int a = 5;
    printf("%d", a--);
    if(a)
        main();    
    return 0;
}
```

[Exemplo executando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/Ka05/0)

E o desafio era responder qual o comportamento que este código teria (compilado usando o GCC).

De cara pensei: "loop infinito". Então fui testar e vi que não é isso, a variável `a` não é atribuída a 5 sempre que o método `main` é chamado. Na verdade, a execução mostra na tela `54321` e é finalizada.

Qual o motivo deste comportamento?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Primeiro entenda [diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) (a pergunta original falava em escopo).

Existem dois tipos de variáveis estáticas em C, uma é a de escopo local (a do exemplo) e outra com escopo do arquivo de código onde ela é acessada por qualquer função do arquivo atual, quase como se fosse uma variável estática membro de classe, mas não é uma classe mesmo.

O tempo de vida de ambas é o mesmo que o tempo de vida da aplicação, afinal a variável é estática. Isso não muda em relação ao C#, por exemplo, a diferença é que o C# ainda não tem uma variável estática local.

Então a única diferença nessa variável é que a visibilidade dela é mais restrita, só pode ser acessada na própria função que foi declarada. O estado dela é global, a visibilidade é que é local. Portanto ela retém o valor e cada execução acessará o valor global dela, não se perde no fim da execução da função.

A área de memória global dessa variável só será inicializada se a função for executada. A inicialização ocorrerá só uma vez.

Nos comentários se falou sobre "intuitividade". Tem um monte de coisa que só é intuitivo quando já se aprendeu algo antes, porque sem um conhecimento prévio a pessoa nem sabe por onde começar. Por outro lado quando a pessoa aprende algo se ela ver outra diferente daquilo tenderá achar que não é intuitivo. Se pensar bem a sintaxe indica bem aquilo, a variável está dentro da função e é local, bem intuitivo, tem uma palavra dizendo que ela é estática, então ele tem tempo de vida por toda a aplicação, bem intuitivo, desde que se entenda o conceito de escopo e tempo de vida. Se não entender isso, outras formas podem ficar confusas também.

Relacionado: [Variável static e #define](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164808/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sinceramente, é uma escolha de design da linguagem contra intuitivo.

Comment: Assim como JS possui `hoisting` que eu acho uma abominação...

Comment: Sei lá, como eu aprendi C logo de cara há quase 35 anos eu acho bem normal, claro que a pessoa pode abusar, mas eu acho bem intuitivo, você tem o estado global que pode ser necessário e visibilidade local que diminui o estrago que pode fazer. A maioria das características das linguagens não é muito intuitiva, a pessoa tem que aprender primeiro, aí ela aprende e acha intuitivo. Em geral o que a pessoa acha que não é intuitivo é o que vai contra o que ela aprendeu primeiro, eu acho um monte de coisa "moderna" contra intuitivo :)

Comment: Faltou dizer que as variáveis estáticas declaradas dentro do escopo de funções só serão inicializadas se houver a chamada dessa função. Caso contrário, ela jamais será inicializada.

Comment: @Lacobus é verdade e já está dito por você, embora não faça diferença fundamental já que ela só pode ser acessada dentro da própria função. Claro que se acessar o endereço onde ela está por outros meios fora do que o compilador permite e a função não não foi chamada, acessará algo não inicializado.