# "#define" define uma variável global?

Tags: c, escopo-de-variáveis, preprocessador, diretivas-de-compilação

Eu sempre utilizei alguns `define`s, mas agora surgiu essa dúvida, quando utilizo um `#define` estou criando uma variável global? Há algum prejuízo nessa utilização? Exemplo:

fazer programa para ler 10 números:

Eu coloco `#define` quantidade 10 e uso quantidade nos parâmetros do for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não, nem perto disso.

`#define` apenas diz que um texto é o mesmo que outro texto, mais nada além disso. Então em todo lugar que seu código tiver esse primeiro texto depois do processamento inicial é trocado pelo segundo texto.

Não tem nada de variável. Nem mesmo constante é, embora pareça com uma. Portanto não cabe falar em escopo também. Aquele nome não existe de fato para o código que é compilado. A troca é feita em todo o código onde estiver valendo o `#define`, ou seja, do momento onde ele é encontrado no código até o fim daquela unidade de compilação.

Na forma como está usando se parece com uma constante, então você tem um nome que é mudado para um valor, literal, o valor só existe ali naquele local, novamente não tem nada de escopo.

Para código mais modernos não se recomenda usar praticamente nada do pré-processador, incluindo o `#define`. Não que deva ser usado nunca, mas é melhor evitar.

Veja:

- [Quando usar const e quando usar #define?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136467/101)
- [Variável static e #define](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164808/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).