# Qual a diferença de Static e Shared?

Tags: vb.net, static

Em Visual Basic .NET temos os keywords `Static` e `Shared`. Até onde sei, `Shared` é para declarar campos que podem ser chamados sem uma instância de seu objeto pai.

```vb
Public Class Aluno
    Public Shared Function CreateAluno() As Aluno
        Return New Aluno
    End Function
End Class
```

No entanto, para que serve o `Static` se `Shared` já faz a mesma coisa que o nome anterior sugere? Quais suas diferenças e usos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade, esses comandos podem ser usados para indicar local de armazenagem e tempo de vida de variáveis (`Static`), incluindo de instâncias, os tais campos, e para métodos em tipos (`Shared`). Tem restrições quando pode usar cada um.

Podemos ver na [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que essas palavras são modificadoras do comportamento do `Dim` usado para declarar variáveis, mas podem ser usadas sem ele.

Para quem sabe C# fica fácil explicar o [`Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), é o `static` do C#. Parece confuso, mas é isso, ele está dizendo que o membro, variável ou método, é estático, portanto pertence ao tipo e não à instância do tipo. Acessa ele de forma global e não através de um objeto. Isso implica que uma variável compartilhada é única na aplicação e você tem que tomar cuidado se houver acesso a ela concorrentemente.

O conceito de variável estática ([`Static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/static?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)) não existe em C#, mas existe em diversas outras linguagens, tais como [C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164808/101), [xBase](https://harbour.github.io/doc/clc53.html#static-cmd) ou [PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104014/101) ([outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49521/101)).

Quando qualifica a variável desta forma está dizendo que o tempo de vida será por toda aplicação, igual ao `Shared`, e que toda vez que acessar seu valor ele estará lá disponível, ele existe uma vez só. A grande diferença é que ele está dentro de um método/função e o valor se mantém entre uma chamada e outra dessa rotina.

Isso tem lá seu perigo e é preciso cuidado para usar, ainda mais se o código pode ser concorrente, mas pode ser útil em alguns cenários (nos *links* acima tem exemplos em outras linguagens), permitindo a simplificação. O exemplo da documentação é uma mostra como pode ser fácil de usar e já ser um abuso.

Então quem sabe C# acha que o `Shared` é a mesma coisa que o `static` do C#, e está certo, mas aí acha que o `Static` pode ser a mesma coisa que `static`, mas ele tem essa função diferente.

Poderiam ter usado a mesma palavra para as duas coisas? Eu acho que sim já que apesar do comportamento diferente em cada contexto, não cria ambiguidade, mas preferiram separar, e faz algum sentido para indicar que é diferente. Só porque a linguagem mãe (BASIC) errou em algumas coisas não precisa errar em tudo.

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Conceptual.md).