# Número de elementos alocados de um ponteiro

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória

Preciso de saber quantos elementos estão alocados no meu ponteiro ponteiro. Por exemplo com vetor, `sizeof(v)/sizeof(v[0])` dessa forma consigo o numero de elementos que esse vetor possui. Gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa, porém com ponteiros.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    int *p = malloc(5*sizeof(int)), n;
    n = sizeof(p)/sizeof(int);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;

}
```

Nesse código eu já sei quanto elementos tem, basta imprimir a variável `n`, porém vou usar isso em uma função onde não sei o valor do `n`.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Não existe uma forma padrão de fazer isto e tentar usar alguma extensão pode ter problemas de interoperabilidade.

Mas também não necessidade de obter essa informação já que ela disponível no código. Neste exemplo o tamanho é 5, então mesmo que fosse possível obter, calcular o tamanho não faz sentido. Se precisa desta informação em vários pontos coloque em uma variável ou constante, o que alias é o que todo mundo faz mesmo que não precise da informação depois, evitando [números mágicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101).

Se precisa usar esse número em outra função passe ele como argumento da função. Obviamente que a função deve ser feita para receber e usar esse número. Uma alternativa é criar uma abstração e cria um tipo que tenha o objeto e o seu tamanho como cabeçalho. De fato é assim em linguagens de mais alto nível, aí não precisa passar mais nada.

Olha que simples:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int n = 5;
    int *p = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    printf("%p = %d\n", (void *)p, n);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/ZrDnPp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pvznzhfr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/MallocSize.c).