# Descobrir se é par ou ímpar em array

Tags: c#, .net, array

Estou tentando definir os números pares e ímpares de um total de 5 números informados pelo usuário em um vetor.

```
        int[] atividade = new int[6];
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insira o " + i + "° numero: ");
            atividade[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());             
        }            
        Console.WriteLine("Os seguintes numeros foram digitados: ");

        foreach (int i in atividade)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `% 2` (MOD) para fazer esta verificação, caso retorne resto 1, é impar, caso contrario, é par. Também melhorei um pouco seu código atual:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] atividade = new int[6];
        string numeros = "", tipo = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            WriteLine($"Insira o {i}° numero: ");
            atividade[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            tipo += atividade[i] % 2 == 1 ? "impar, " : "par, ";
            numeros += atividade[i] + ", ";
        }
        Clear();
        Write($"Os seguintes numeros foram digitados: \n{numeros}\n{tipo}");
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/LWaHVV).

Answer (score 2):

Em um código otimizado e moderno, já que está aprendendo, acho interessante saber como realmente se faz, eu poderia fazer mais simples, mas não aprenderá técnicas comuns no dia a dia.

Um erro no seu algoritmo é confiar na entrada de dados. Se a pessoa digitar algo inválido seu programa quebrará. Assim usei o método correto e verifiquei se o que foi digitado é válido. Se não for ele pedirá o número de novo sem incrementar a variável de controle do *array*.

Criei o *array* com tamanho 5 que foi o que deseja. *arrays* começam em 0 e terminam sempre no seu tamanho menos um, já que o 0 é um item. Imagino que tenha criado com 6 porque estava dando erro no último item. Não comece pelo 1, isto desperdiça um item e é fora de padrão, você pode até saber o que fazer, mas outros programadores e não saberão e quando for interagir com *arrays* de outros componentes haverá uma impedância entre eles e terá que fazer ajustes, isto se perceber que há um *bug* no código, pode passar batido.

Também usei uma constante, assim se quiser mudar o número de itens só precisa mudar em um lugar. Veja sobre [O que são "Números Mágicos"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101).

```
using static System.Console;

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
        const int tamanho = 5;
        var atividade = new int[tamanho];
        var i = 0;
        while (i < tamanho) {
            WriteLine($"Insira o {i}° numero: ");
            if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out atividade[i])) i++;
        }
        WriteLine("Os seguintes numeros foram digitados: ");
        foreach (var item in atividade) WriteLine($"{item} é {((item & 1) == 0 ? "par" : "impar")}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1TMU0r). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OF5Ngf). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/OddEven.cs).

Veja [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).