# Qual o significado do termo “Hard Coded”?

Tags: terminologia, desempenho

O que significa o termo *Hard Coded*?

É considerado uma má prática de programação?

Como exemplificar um código *Hard Coded* e sua consequências desde o desenvolvimento até a utilização pelo usuário final?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> O que significa o termo Hard Coded?

Significa que uma informação relevante para o funcionamento do sistema foi colocado no código. Em geral estamos falando de dados, mas em casos mais específicos pode ser um comportamento, muitas vezes usando um sistema de *plugins*.

Não confundir com [números mágicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101).

- Um exemplo é colocar um senha no código, talvez para testar se a pessoa digitou uma válida, isso é um problema de segurança por várias razões, algumas não tão óbvias, é ruim, é inflexível.
- Você coloca a taxa de imposto de algo e o governo muda esse valor, a única forma de mudar isso é mudar o código, recompilar e fazer o *deploy* novamente, tendo que fazer uma mudança na execução, que em alguns cenários é ruim.
- Você coloca que criará 4 *threads* e entra em um ambiente que tem 2 ou 8 processadores, e não fica tão otimizado quanto poderia porque o número está *hard coded* no executável (porque estava no código).
- Você manda gravar no C:, mas o usuário fez uma instalação diferente e ele não tem ou não quer usar o C: para gravar algo, pronto, você está em uma sinuca de bico.
- Uma função trabalha com 10 itens em algo que ela recebe, mas em algum momento há uma mudança e vem 12 itens que você deveria avaliar.
- Você cria um objeto de forma fixa, mas no futuro podem existir outros objetos possíveis para aquele cenário. Claro que depende do cenário como é usado para considerar assim.
- Você estabelece como é um formato de dados que devem vir de algum lugar, pode ser uma consulta ao banco de dados, se a fonte muda sua estrutura tem que mudar a aplicação. Não estou fazendo juízo se é isso é bom ou não, tudo tem vantagens e desvantagens, esse é i caso que muitas aplicação são *hard coded* e isso é bom, porque é raro ter vantagens ou mesmo possível ser flexível de verdade sem ter custos importantes.

Existem casos de meio termo, no executável está *hard coded*, mas não no código. Isso ajuda o desenvolvimento e para alguns casos pode ser só o que deseja, nem sempre eliminar do executável é o objetivo. Em geral usa-se geradores de código para isso, facilita muito a manutenção sem gerar custos de execução.

Você deve perguntar para um serviço qualquer (pode ser o sistema operacional ou até algo externo) o que usar, ou colocar dados em arquivo externo de configuração ou outra utilidade, ou em um banco de dados, ou outra forma que não venha do código.

É a boa e velha [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) que resolve isso.

> É considerado uma má prática de programação?

Depende do contexto, em alguns é sim, em outros pode ser o oposto. Já dei exemplos. Por que eu pediria para uma fonte externa quantos dias da semana existem? Por que eu imporia um custo adicional sem um ganho claro?

> Como exemplificar um código Hard Coded e sua consequências desde o desenvolvimento até a utilização pelo usuário final?

Já respondi antes?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Depende do contexto.
Em inglês, no contexto de progrmamação, Hardcoded pode significar que determinado valor é estático. Quando declaramos, por exemplo, `nome="João Silva"`, estamos definindo que a variável `nome` tem o valor estático `"João Silva"`. Esta variável está, portanto, "hardcoded". Se, por outro lado, temos a mesma variável definida da seguinte forma: `nome=primeiroNome + sobrenome`, sendo nome e sobrenome outras duas variáveis, o valor de `nome` deixa de ser estático e varia em função do valor das outras duas variáveis.

Particularmente, nunca escutei ou li esta palavra, em textos ou vídeos em inglês, com outras conotações.

Comment: Editei a resposta porque ela só deve ter informações que respondam à pergunta. Se tem outro questionamento, basta [fazer outra pergunta](/questions/ask) - mas caso a pergunta seja mais sobre a língua portuguesa e menos sobre programação, sugiro que a faça [aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com). Quanto a responder a própria pergunta, sim, é normal e perfeitamente aceitável - leia a [Central de Ajuda](/help/self-answer) para entender melhor

Comment: Quanto ao uso do termo "hardcoded", pode até ser que o significado original seja o que vc mencionou, mas em programação - pelo menos no Brasil - ele acabou ganhando outros usos e conotações - todos eles, aliás, citados na outra resposta, então a meu ver não há equívoco nenhum nela

Comment: Só para terminar, nesse caso não foi a mesma pessoa que perguntou e respondeu. A que respondeu só editou a pergunta, por isso o nome dela também aparece lá. Mas de qualquer forma, mesmo que tivesse sido a mesma pessoa, isso seria perfeitamente normal, como já dito acima

Comment: Obrigado pelas orientações. Perguntei sobre o equivalente ao termo no fórum indicado.