# Tem como saber o tamanho de um array no VisualG?

Tags: array, declaração-de-variável, visualg

```
para i de 1 ate array.length faca
     escreval("Falta ", i, "?")
     leia(falta[i])
     i <- (i + 1)
     fimpara
```

Por exemplo, no Java é `array.length`.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu sei não tem, até porque em VisualG o *array* sempre tem tamanho fixo e definido previamente na declaração de variáveis, então o tamanho é sempre conhecido pelo seu código, não tem porque existir um mecanismo que diga isso.

É verdade que isso cria vício, mas pra exercício está bom. Só entenda que não é assim que se faz em código real, assim como não se declara variável antes de usar, isso é uma limitação da linguagem que está usando.

Pode usar uma constante ou até variável com o tamanho, e aí usar na declaração e onde precisar dessa informação, assim evita os [números mágicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101). É uma boa prática, mas para exercício importa pouco, ajuda não pegar um vício, mas estará pegando outros de qualquer jeito.

Se quer ter algo sem saber o tamanho previamente então faça em Java e quase qualquer outra linguagem que permite isso.