# sizeof não funciona para determinar o tamanho do malloc()

Tags: c, c++, malloc, sizeof

Estava fazendo um trabalho de estrutura de dados quando me deparei com a necessidade de alocar um vetor dinamicamente, entretanto, mesmo alocando o espaço necessário para a estrutura, o valor retornado por `sizeof` é incorreto. Segue o exemplo do código:

```
int *vetor = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);//alocando espaço para 4 inteiros ou seja 4*4 = 16 bytes

printf("%d -- %d\n", sizeof(vetor), sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int));//printando o valo
```

Nesse exemplo acima `sizeof(vetor)` deveria nos retornar o tamanho do vetor, ou seja a quantidade de bytes que destinamos a ele, correto?

E portanto, a saída esperada seria:

> 16 -- 4

Porém, não é isso o que acontece. Segue exemplo da saída:

[image: Saída]

E não importa quantos bytes eu destine ao vetor com `malloc`, a saída é sempre a mesma, ou seja, tamanho do vetor em bytes é sempre 8.

Por que isso acontece, e qual seria a resolução para esse problema?

Comment: Conceito 1: sizeof() de um ponteiro é sempre 4 em um compilador de 32-bits, ou 8 em 64-bits. sizeof() é resolvido em tempo de *compilação* não em tempo de execução. Não haveria como ele inspecionar o resultado de um malloc já que malloc não deixa de ser uma função qualquer, que poderia se chamar abacate(), banana() ou caqui() e realizar a mesma coisa.
Conceito 2: malloc retorna um bloco de bytes que nem inicializados estão. Você é responsavel pelo seu uso. Embora o gerenciador de memória saiba como esse foi alocado (para que free() faça o seu papel), essa informação está em uma área privada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está afirmando duas coisas, e fazendo uma pergunta assumindo que essas duas coisas sejam fato. No entanto

- não está "alocando o espaço necessário"
- e tampouco "o valor retornado por `sizeof()` é incorreto"

Eis a declaração de `vetor`

```
int        *vetor = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
```

Não quero entrar em discussões religiosas aqui, mas está declarando `vetor` e `vetor` é `int*` então talvez ficasse mais claro para ler, em especial para quem está aprendendo, se escrevesse

```
int*        vetor = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
```

`sizeof(vetor)` retorna de fato o tamanho de `vetor`. `vetor` é `int*`, um ponteiro para `int`. E o tamanho do ponteiro é dado pela arquitetura da máquina, 8 bytes no seu caso, para compilar em 64 bits.

> "E não importa quantos bytes eu destine ao vetor com malloc, a saída é
> sempre a mesma, ou seja, tamanho do vetor em bytes é sempre 8"

nisso você está certo: uma coisa é `vetor`, um ponteiro para `int`. Outra coisa é o tamanho da área para a qual ele aponta, que foi nesse caso determinada pela conta
`malloc(sizeof(int)*4)`.

No caso do tamanho da área alocada não há oficialmente uma maneira de você saber qual é, e a razão é simples: foi você que alocou então deve saber. E para o sistema ele mantém uma tabela interna desses valores. Veja esse trecho de exemplo

```
int tamanho = 1801;
int* mais_um_vetor = (int*)malloc(tamanho);
free(mais_um_vetor);
mais_um_vetor = (int*)malloc(130);
tamanho = 32 * sizeof(int);
int* p = (int*)realloc(mais_um_vetor, tamanho);
if (p != NULL) mais_um_vetor = p;
free(mais_um_vetor);
```

`malloc()` não tem aritmética de tamanho: vai alocar 1801 bytes e colocar o endereço em `mais_um_vetor`, um ponteiro para `int`. Não vai alocar 1801 `int`! Como o tamanho da área não é múltiplo de `sizeof(int)` deve cancelar seu programa ao tentar acessar de 4 em 4 se usar `mais_um_vetor` como um vetor de `int`

Mas depois `free()` roda ok e libera os 1801. E `malloc()` aloca 130 para o mesmo ponteiro.
Talvez por ter lembrado que devia ser múltiplo de `sizeof(int)` o programa chama `realloc()` e aloca espaço para 32 int. E salva em tamanho o total da área.

Em geral o que importa é o saldo, uma questão contábil: `free()` vai liberar o que `malloc()` alocou. Saldo zero. Não importa quanto era e em geral não é preciso saber o tamanho da área alocada. Claro que precisa saber o tamanho da área a alocar, e na hora de liberar o sistema sabe o tamanho e é só o que importa.

Note que esse exemplo é só isso: um exemplo sem sentido, incluído aí o programa ao final.

Note que para `realloc()` também não faz diferença o tamanho da área. Só o NOVO tamanho.

Foram alocados 1800, depois liberados e alocados 130. `sizeof(mais_um_vetor)` não vai mudar: 8. E o sistema mantem registro do tamanho da área para quando você chamar `free()` para liberar ou `realloc()` para mudar o tamanho, e a coisa funciona.

**No entanto provavelmente não é isso que você quer**

Você que acessar `vetor` como um vetor de `int`, com um número arbitrário de valores, alocados dinamicamente.

**Como fazer isso?**

Você pode alocar o número exato, partindo de `N=1` e usando `realloc()` para alocar `N=N+1` a cada vez, ou pode alocar em blocos de um certo número, como em blocos de 64 `int`, para ficar um pouco mais eficiente.

O problema é que `realloc()` pode ter que mudar todo mundo de lugar, a critério do sistema, e não vai te avisar antes. E isso claro vai custar um tempo ao seu programa, de uma hora para outra. Em programas de estudo isso não é relevante, mas acho que entendeu o problema: o bloco que alocou está no meio de possíveis outas coisas que seu programa alocou, e ao `realloc()` precisar de mais uns bytes pode não ter na hora e então vai alocar uma área maior em outro lugar e copiar tudo que tinha na área original. E seu programa vai ter que esperar.

Antes que você pergunte: para diminuir é garantido que o endereço do ponteiro não muda. Para aumentar só é garantido que o conteúdo até o momento do aumento não vai mudar.

Então o que você quer alocar na verdade é

```
int**        vetor;
```

`vetor` deve apontar para um vetor de ponteiros para `int`, e não para um único `int` como o caso de

```
int*         vetor;
```

Isso é exatamente o que o sistema faz para cada programa em C, montando o vetor `argv[]` com `argc` elementos, e fica claro porque precisa do `argc`: alguém tem que avisar ao programa o tamanho do vetor de argumentos.

Assim como alguém tem que avisar ao seu vetor para quantos int ele aponta

**Um programa de exemplo**

aloca um vetor de 32 ponteiros para `int`, aloca os caras e põe um valor de 100 a 131 em cada um. Mostra o primeiro e o último valor e depois apaga tudo. E depois aloca, preenche e apaga um array de 3 int.

**Saída:**

```
sizeof(vetor) 8
sizeof(int) 4
sizeof(vetor) = 8
sizeof(outro_vetor)  int outro_vetor[30] = 120
alocado um vetor de 32 int
Primeiro: 100 Ultimo 131
Liberando o vetor...
Liberado...
Alocando vetor de 3 int...
sizeof() = 8
3 4 5
Final...
```

**O programa:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int* vetor = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    printf("sizeof(vetor) %zu\n", sizeof(vetor));
    printf("sizeof(int) %zu\n", sizeof(int));

    int     outro_vetor[30];
    vetor = outro_vetor;

    printf("sizeof(vetor) = %zu\n", sizeof(vetor));
    printf("sizeof(outro_vetor)  int outro_vetor[30] = %zu\n",
        sizeof(outro_vetor));

    int tamanho = 1801;
    int* mais_um_vetor = (int*)malloc(tamanho);
    free(mais_um_vetor);
    mais_um_vetor = (int*)malloc(130);
    tamanho = 32 * sizeof(int);
    int* p = (int*)realloc(mais_um_vetor, tamanho);
    if (p != NULL) mais_um_vetor = p;
    free(mais_um_vetor);

    // cria vetor_de_int apontando para intN int
    int     intN = 32;
    int** vetor_de_int = NULL;

    // passo a passo (podia ter feito direto)
    vetor_de_int = (int**)malloc(intN * sizeof(int*));
    for (int n = 0; n < 32; n += 1)
    {
        vetor_de_int[n] = malloc(sizeof(int*)); // aloca um
        *vetor_de_int[n] = 100 + n; // valores de 100 a 131
    };  // for()

    printf("alocado um vetor de %d int\n", intN);
    printf("Primeiro: %d Ultimo %d\n",
        *vetor_de_int[0],
        *vetor_de_int[intN-1]
    );

    // destroi tudo, como em C++ ao contrario 
    // da criacao
    printf("Liberando o vetor...\n");
        for (int n = 0; n < 32; n += 1)
        free(vetor_de_int[n]);
    // liberado o vetor, agora a tabela
    free(vetor_de_int);
    printf("Liberado...\n");

    printf("Alocando vetor de 3 int...\n");

    int     (*vetor3_int)[3] = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof() = %zu\n", sizeof(vetor3_int));
    (*vetor3_int)[0] = 3;
    (*vetor3_int)[1] = 4;
    (*vetor3_int)[2] = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i += 1)
        printf("%d ", (*vetor3_int)[i]);
    free(vetor3_int);
    printf("\nFinal...\n");
    return 0;
};
```

**Mas o primeiro não é um vetor de int...**

Pois é. é um vetor de `int*`. Na prática é o que se quer. Em especial em estruturas de dados. Se você quer alocar um vetor de 32 `int` você declara

```
int     (*vetor32_int)[32] = malloc(32 * sizeof(int));
```

Só que aí é muito menos flexível: na memória está ok, E o tamanho está definido. Mas só serve para 32. Fixo.

Por isso o normal é usar um par de variáveis, como o sistema usa, e alocar em blocos de um tamanho razoável, para não ter nem muito desperdício nem muitas operações de `realloc()`

Comment: MEU DEUS, que explicação incrível! Agora tudo faz mais sentido, e portanto, sempre devo manter o tamanho guardado em algum lugar e ao mesmo tempo nem sempre utilizar o dinamismo, mantendo o equilíbrio entre desperdício de memória e o desperdício de computação (copiar todo o vetor de um lugar para o outro na memória devido a falta de espaço contínuo com o realloc), correto?

Comment: É. Você viu no final do exemplo que é possível alocar dinamicamente um ponteiro para um certo número de `int` --- 3 no exemplo --- ou de qualquer coisa, como `float  (*vetor)[32]`. Só que tem que ser conhecido na hora de compilar o programa e em geral não adianta. No seu caso por exemplo você vai ler o valor de `N`quando o programa está rodando

Comment: O lance de realloc() é que nem sempre se pode correr o risco do programa dar uma parada numa hora importante, porque o sistema está transferindo GB de dados em uma chamada de realloc(). Um meio termo é alocar em blocos de um tamanho estudado, de modo a ter menos desperdício e um mínimo de realloc(). Algo como usar blocos de ponteiros para um certo número de estruturas, dependendo dos seus dados. Ou sofisticar de vez e usar páginas de ponteiros, como o sistema faz com a memória. Sem realocar nada. Mas muitas vezes nem se precisa saber o tamanho no programa, ou mesmo usar realloc().

Comment: Estruturas de dados como árvores, pilhas e  listas tem os nós alocados um a um em geral, por exemplo.

Answer (score 6):

O cálculo que está fazendo só serve para um *array* com tamanho definido em tempo de compilação. Apesar de estar usando um constante na alocação dinâmica ela é potencialmente desconhecida e não funciona. O operador `sizeof` só consegue obter uma informação que o compilador pode provar que seja constante, e é complicado para ele provar isso, até porque nesse caso até não é tão difícil analisar, mas tem código mais complexo que não dá para saber esse valor.

Então,

- ou você aloca um *array* na pilha onde o compilador consegue saber o tamanho, e não vejo motivo algum para não fazer isso (pode existir, mas em geral não é necessário alocação dinâmica em casos simples),
- ou usa o valor que você já sabe que é o 4 em vez de fazer uma conta que nem faz sentido. Se está usando o código em outra função tem que passar esse valor junto para a função saber,
  ou em alguns casos usa uma constante global assim tendo um nome em todo lugar e fica mais [fácil trocar o número em todos os lugares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101).

Enfim, tem várias formas de resolver isso dependendo do contexto, que não conhecemos.

Só para completeza, o 8 que aparece aí é o tamanho do ponteiro e não o tamanho do vetor. `vetor` é de um tipo ponteiro, você declarou dizendo que é, não pode esperar que magicamente ele mostre o tamanho de outra coisa. Em arquiteturas 64 bits todos ponteiros são de tamanho 8. Um *array* alocado na *stack* não é um ponteiro, é o dado e o tamanho é conhecido, até para o compilador saber o espaço que precisa reservar. Dinamismo é usado quando você não sabe o valor. Se não sabe o valor precisa criar mecanismos de controle próprios para manter o tamanho, aí a segunda opção que listei acima é a recomendada, dá até para sofisticar isso, mas não vou falar sobre porque é avançado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi, muito boa a explicação. Porém em casos em que eu não saberia o valor exato do tamanho do vetor como eu procederia? Esse é o caso que enfrento, coloquei o 4 apenas para simbologia e facilitar a explicação do problema, entretanto, no caso real eu não possuo informação sobre o tamanho real do vetor... Deveria proceder de forma a alocar um tamanho mínimo e realocar o tamanho com iterações, salvando o valor do index da iteração final como len? ou existe um método melhor para fazê-lo? Grato pela atenção!

Comment: Parte disso está no segundo parágrafo, parte já é outra pergunta, mas é está no caminho certo, você tem que controlar o tamanho na mão de alguma forma, C não tem nada pronto.