# Alocar Memória de Atributo em Estrutura

Tags: c, struct, alocação

Preciso alocar mais memória do atributo nota da estrutura Aluno:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Aluno
{
    int matricula;
    int nota;
};

void cadastraNotas(struct Aluno* cadastro, int aluno, int *qtdNotas)
{
        printf("\nInforme a quantidade de notas do aluno %d: ", cadastro[aluno].matricula);
        scanf("%d", &qtdNotas[aluno]);

        if(qtdNotas[aluno] > 1) {
          
          //Aqui estou em dúvida como escrever
          cadastro[aluno].nota = realloc(cadastro[aluno].nota, qtdNotas[aluno] * sizeof(struct Aluno)); 
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < qtdNotas[aluno]; i++)
        {
            printf("Informe a nota %d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &cadastro[aluno].nota[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Note que você declarou nota como int e não como um ponteiro para int.

Comment: Funcionou, alterei a variável nota para ponteiro (int *nota). Valeu!

Comment: Falta muito código no trecho postado, mas me parece estranha esta sua realocação do ponteiro nota, em particular este `sizeof(struct Aluno)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Poste um programa inteiro de modo que alguém possa facilmente testar se achar que pode te ajudar.**

```
    struct Aluno
    {
        int matricula;
        int nota;
    };
    
    void cadastraNotas(struct Aluno* cadastro, int aluno, int *qtdNotas)
    
    ...
```

Acho que deve pensar mais sobre os dados e como pretende usar isso. De um modo geral Aluno pode ter umas notas e um cadastro pode ter uns alunos. Há 3 maneiras comuns de tratar isso:

- [a] fixar um máximo de notas para um Aluno e de Alunos para uma Turma
- [b] usar uma estrutura de dados, como uma lista ligada por exemplo, e ir alocando notas e alunos conforme a execução
- [c] usar alocação dinâmica e alocar conforme necessário notas e alunos, como faz o sistema ao montar a lista de parâmetros para `main()` que é declarada

```
    int main( int argc, char** argv);
```

Exemplo simples usando valores fixos

```
typedef struct 
{
    int matricula;
    int N; // quantas notas
    int nota[10];

}   Aluno;

typedef struct
{
    const char* codigo;
    int     N;
    Aluno   aluno[10];

}   Turma;
```

Nesse caso você pode ter até 10 notas por aluno e até 10 alunos por turma, mas é tudo fixo, estático. É fácil de escrever mas nada flexível...

#### Veja um exemplo do caso [a]:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int matricula;
    int N; // quantas notas
    int nota[10];

}   Aluno;

typedef struct
{
    const char* codigo;
    int     N;
    Aluno   aluno[10];

}   Turma;

int     mostra_turma(Turma*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Turma turmaA =
    { .codigo = "Fisica II",
        .N = 0
    };
    mostra_turma(&turmaA); // vazia

    // poe uns alunos na turma
    Aluno um = { 128, 4, { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
    Aluno outro =
    {
        .N = 3,
        .matricula = 1234,
        .nota = { 1, 1, 1 }
    };
    turmaA.aluno[turmaA.N] = um;
    turmaA.N += 1;
    turmaA.aluno[turmaA.N] = outro;
    turmaA.N += 1;
    mostra_turma(&turmaA);
    return 0;
};  // main()

int     mostra_turma(Turma* T)
{
    printf("Turma '%s' tem %d alunos\n\n",
        T->codigo, T->N);
    for (int i = 0; i < T->N; i += 1)
    {
        Aluno* al = &T->aluno[i];
        printf("Mat #%d\t%d Notas: ", al->matricula, al->N);
        for (int j = 0; j < al->N; j += 1)
            printf("%d ", al->nota[j]);
        printf("\n");
    };
    printf("\n");
    return T->N;
};  // mostra_turma()
```

Pode ser que só isso já te sirva e ao menos mostra como endereçar as estruturas de turma e aluno.

Esse programa mostra

```
Turma 'Fisica II' tem 0 alunos


Turma 'Fisica II' tem 2 alunos

Mat #128        4 Notas: 1 2 3 4
Mat #1234       3 Notas: 1 1 1
```

#### [b] usando uma lista ligada

Usar uma lista ligada permitiria gravar os alunos um a um e apagar mais facilmente um cara no meio da turma por exemplo, e é bem flexível. É mais lento claro, e mais complicado. Mas com tudo estático não serve para quase nada.

Para o caso de usar uma lista não vou postar um programa aqui porque seria apenas uma lista ligada de `Turma` onde cada `Aluno` teria uma lista de `Nota`. O mesmo modelo.
Mas vou postar uma estrutura que funciona, assim saberá o que escrever se precisar disso.
É bem simples se já tem uma implementação de lista ligada ou se alguém te ceder uma. Outras linguagens já tem isso disponível. E se escrever sua primeira lista pode fazer de modo a poder usar em outros casos sem ter que mudar nada: por isso são chamadas de estruturas abstratas de dados afinal.

A lista ligada tem nós e tem uma estrutura de controle, coisas genericamente chamadas de *metadados*. Você pode escrever sem isso mas vai trabalhar pra caramba a toa.

#### uma possibilidade usando listas ligadas

```
struct no
{
    void* item;
    struct no* proxima;
    struct no* anterior;
};  // no
typedef struct no Node;

struct a_propria_lista
{
    char* nome;
    unsigned  quantos;
    unsigned  maximo;
    Node* inicio;
    Node* fim;
};
typedef struct a_propria_lista Lista;

typedef struct
{
    int     matricula;
    Lista*  notas;

}   Aluno;

typedef struct
{
    const char* codigo;
    Lista*      alunos;

}   Turma;
```

A `Turma` poderia ser apenas uma `Lista` mas é pouco versátil. É melhor deixar o modelo assim, para poder acrescentar dados à `Turma` e deixar a `Lista` só com os alunos. Mesmo caso para as `notas`. Como a `Lista` sempre tem o tamanho conhecido não precisa mais dos campos de tamanho que eram importantes no caso (a): se você declarou

```
Turma* turma_dois;
```

Então

```
size(turma_dois->alunos);
```

vai sempre retornar o total de alunos na turma. E de modo semelhante para as notas.

Claro, sempre se escreve um mínimo de funções para uma lista, e o mínimo inclui uma função `size()` que devolve o tamanho.

Como cada nó da lista é apenas um ponteiro para um item, `void* item`, a conta fecha e você pode usar as mesmas funções de lista para ler `Turma` e `Aluno`.

#### [c] Usando um vetor de estruturas

Esse é um caminho muito rápido para executar e percorrer, mas pode ser chato se vai ficar editando Turma durante a execução ou criando novas notas. Há que se optar.

**Eis um exemplo**

```
typedef struct
{
    int     matricula;
    int     N;
    int**   nota;

}   AlunoC;

typedef struct
{
    const char* codigo;
    int         N;
    AlunoC**    aluno;

}   TurmaC;
```

Nesse caso é possível iterar pelos alunos na Turma usando

```
TurmaC    sala1;
```

e endereçar os alunos como um vetor, usando

```
*aluno[0], *aluno[1]...
```

até o fim da lista. Só que você precisa manter noção do fim da lista, e por isso o parâmetro `N` está de volta. É como o `argc` de `main()`. Sem ele a coisa não anda porque não há como saber onde termina o tal vetor.

```
int**   nota;
```

por exemplo declara um ponteiro. Nada mais. Só que é um ponteiro para um ponteiro para `int`.

- `nota` é `int**`
- `*nota` é `int*`
- `**nota` é um `int`.

Se você alocar 10 ponteiros para `int` e colocar o endereço em `nota` pode iterar pelos alunos usando `*nota[0]` até `*nota[9]` e isso é muito, mas muito útil mesmo.

Eu postei [aqui no SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469215/108192) um programa exemplo que faz isso, com resultados e discussão. O programa cria um bloco dinâmico desses, usando strings, para explicar o que o sistema faz para montar o bloco de argumentos para `main()`, e passa para uma função

```
    int nova_main(int argc, char** argv)
```

que lista os caras. Não posso agora replicar aqui, talvez depois.

Escrevi [um outro exemplo usando um vetor de `int**`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/468229/108192) como é o seu caso com as notas aqui.

> Pode ver esses dois exemplos e se achar útil e tiver alguma pergunta
> me avise e eu posso depois editar um exemplo para esse caso aqui.