# Erro na Alocação de Memória em Estrutura

Tags: c, struct, alocação

PROGRAMA
O programa realoca memória conforme forem adicionados mais alunos ou mais notas, porém, em certos testes dependendo da quantidade de alunos ou notas ele pega valores "sujos" da memória e joga para os primeiros valores já alocados.

ERRO
1 - Cadastra dois alunos na opção 1 do menu, cada um com 2 notas;
2 - Mostra a média na opção 2 do menu (até aqui OK);
3 - Cadastra mais dois alunos na opção 1 do menu, cada um com 2 notas;
4 - Aqui ocorre erro no valor da nota 2 do aluno 1, consequentemente os valores da maior nota e media geral também estão incorretos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Aluno
{
    int matricula;
    int *nota;
};

void cadastraAluno(struct Aluno* cadastro, int aluno)
{
    printf("\nAluno(%d)\n- Informe a matricula: ", aluno + 1);
    scanf("%d", &cadastro[aluno].matricula);
}

void cadastraNotas(struct Aluno* cadastro, int aluno, int *qtdNotas)
{
    printf("- Informe a quantidade de notas para cadastrar: ");
    scanf("%d", &qtdNotas[aluno]);

    cadastro[aluno].nota = malloc(qtdNotas[aluno] * sizeof(struct Aluno));

    for(int i = 0; i < qtdNotas[aluno]; i++)
    {
        printf("- Informe a nota %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &cadastro[aluno].nota[i]);
    }
}

void verificaNotas(struct Aluno* cadastro, int alunosTotal, int *maiorNt, int *menorNt, int *qtdNotas)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < alunosTotal; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < qtdNotas[i]; j++)
        {
            if(cadastro[i].nota[j] > *maiorNt)
            {
                *maiorNt = cadastro[i].nota[j];
            }
            if(cadastro[i].nota[j] < *menorNt)
            {
                *menorNt = cadastro[i].nota[j];
            }
        }
    }
}

void mediaNotas(struct Aluno* cadastro, int alunosTotal, int *qtdNotas, float *media)
{
    float somaNotas = 0, somaTotal = 0, qtdNt = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < alunosTotal; i++)
    {
        printf("\n-> Aluno(%d)\nMatricula %d", i + 1, cadastro[i].matricula);
        somaNotas = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < qtdNotas[i]; j++)
        {
            printf("\nNota %d: %d", j + 1, cadastro[i].nota[j]);
            somaNotas = somaNotas + cadastro[i].nota[j];
            qtdNt++;
        }
        somaTotal = somaNotas + somaTotal;
        printf("\n");
    }
    *media = somaTotal / qtdNt;
}

void imprimirInfo(float media, int maiorNt, int menorNt, int alunos)
{
    printf("\n------------------------------\n");
    printf("- Total de Alunos: %d\n", alunos);
    printf("- Menor Nota: %d\n", menorNt);
    printf("- Maior Nota: %d\n", maiorNt);
    printf("- Media Geral: %.0f", media);
    printf("\n------------------------------\n");
}


int main()
{
    int alunos = 0, op, maiorNota = 0, menorNota = 10, aux = 0, alunosTot = 0, pos = 0, *qtdNotas, *qtdNotas1;
    struct Aluno *cadastro;
    struct Aluno *cadastro1;
    float mediaTotal;

    do
    {
        printf("\nEscolha uma opcao abaixo:");
        printf("\n0 - Encerrar o Programa\n");
        printf("1 - Cadastrar Aluno\n");
        printf("2 - Calcular Media da Turma\n");
        scanf("%d", &op);

        switch (op)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Informe o numero de alunos: ");
            scanf("%d", &alunos);

            if (aux == 0)
            {
                qtdNotas = (int*) malloc(alunos * sizeof(int));
                cadastro = (struct Aluno*) malloc(alunos * sizeof(struct Aluno));
            }
            else
            {
                qtdNotas1 = (int*) realloc(qtdNotas, alunos * sizeof(int));
                cadastro1 = (struct Aluno*) realloc(cadastro, alunos * sizeof(struct Aluno));

                if (qtdNotas1 != NULL)
                {
                    qtdNotas = qtdNotas1;
                }
                if (cadastro1 != NULL)
                {
                    cadastro = cadastro1;
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < alunos; i++)
            {
                cadastraAluno(cadastro, pos);
                cadastraNotas(cadastro, pos, qtdNotas);

                pos++;
            }
            aux++;
            alunosTot += alunos;

            break;

        case 2:
            if(alunos == 0)
            {
                printf("\nVoce precisa cadastrar um ou mais alunos\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n------------------------------");
                verificaNotas(cadastro, alunosTot, &maiorNota, &menorNota, qtdNotas);
                mediaNotas(cadastro, alunosTot, qtdNotas, &mediaTotal);
                imprimirInfo(mediaTotal, maiorNota, menorNota, alunosTot);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    while(op != 0);

    free(cadastro);
    free(qtdNotas);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se `nota` é um ponteiro para int qual o sentido de fazer: `cadastro[aluno].nota = malloc(qtdNotas[aluno] * sizeof(struct Aluno));`? Por qual motivo você faz um `realloc` mas atribui a um ponteiro diferente?

Comment: O sentido do **malloc** seria para cadastrar mais de uma nota, pois, para cada aluno pode ver uma ou mais notas. Isso é perguntado no sistema a cada aluno que é cadastrado. O **realloc** apontando para outro ponteiro seria para evitar de perder os dados do primeiro ponteiro, caso ocorra erro.

Comment: Mas porquê multiplicar por `sizeof(struct Aluno)`?

Comment: Entendi, o correto seria  sizeof(int), seria isso? Pois nota é do tipo int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Aluno
{
    int matricula;
    int *nota;
};
```

Essa é a estrutura Aluno, mas parece que ser também seu cadastro
a julgar pelas declarações em `main()`

```
    struct Aluno *cadastro;
    struct Aluno *cadastro1;
```

Só que não é assim que funciona. Vou tentar explicar abaixo. Eu acho que já fiz isso em relação a um problema idêntico a esse mas não encontrei referência

#### Antes:

- se está aprendendo agora evite ao máximo linhas como essa abaixo. Inicialize todas as variáveis, mas não declare mais que uma por linha. É de graça. Ajuda você e aos outros. Veja

```
    int alunos = 0, op, maiorNota = 0, menorNota = 10, aux = 0, alunosTot = 0, pos = 0, *qtdNotas, *qtdNotas1;
```

E compare com isso

```
    int alunos = 0;
    int op;
    int maiorNota = 0;
    int menorNota = 10;
    int aux = 0;
    int alunosTot = 0;
    int pos = 0; 
    int *qtdNotas, 
    int *qtdNotas1;
```

Não acha mais fácil de ler? E se for você tentando ler isso daqui a duas semanas?

Porque não inicializou justamente os ponteiros, os mais prováveis pra te dar um problema?

- Use main() sempre como a primeira função de seu programa. Assim você ajuda outros e a você mesmo a entender seu programa.

#### De volta ao programa

- `Aluno`: sua estrutura tem um ponteiro para `nota` e isso não vai te dar acesso a mais de uma nota. Isso depois que você alocar algum espaço para ela.
- `struct Aluno*` cadastro também é um ponteiro para um único `Aluno`. Não cria um cadastro de Alunos. E por enquanto é só um ponteiro. Você pode alocar via `malloc()` 150 alunos usando esse ponteiro. O parâmetro de `malloc()` é apenas o tamanho da área. É correto escrever, até onde o compilador vê, `struct Aluno* Sala = malloc(2048);`
  e alocar 2K a partir de `Sala`. Mas isso não vai fazer você poder iterar por `Sala`, como em `Sala[0]`, `Sala[1]` ou algo assim.
  É o mesmo caso da das notas no registro de `Aluno`.
  A maneira mais flexível de fazer isso é declarar algo como

```
typedef struct
{
    int     matricula;
    int     N;
    int**   nota;

}   Aluno;

typedef struct
{
    char*   turma;
    int     id;
    int     N;
    Aluno** al;

}   Sala;

Sala QuimicaI;
Aluno um;
```

Ou algo conservador, alocando um número pré fixado de Alunos e Notas, como em

```
typedef struct
{
    int     matricula;
    int     N;
    int     nota[5];

}   Aluno;

typedef struct
{
    char*   turma;
    int     id;
    int     N;
    Aluno   al[10];

}   Sala;

Sala QuimicaI;
Aluno um;
```

Nada flexível mas bem mais simples. Eu postei exemplos completos de uso de int** e char** que pode adaptar para esse caso. Não vou repetir o código aqui mas os links são [para um programa em C que cria usa e libera um bloco char**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469215/108192) e esse [para um programa que cria e usa um bloco int**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/468229/108192)

Talvez ajude se você olhar lá. u posso postar depois algo aqui se não entender o que está lá ou tiver uma questão específica.

Comment: _1. Não acha mais fácil de ler? E se for você tentando ler isso daqui a duas semanas._ Agradeço a dica de formatação de inicialização de variáveis, vou começar a utilizar dessa forma. _2. Porque não inicializou justamente os ponteiros, os mais prováveis pra te dar um problema?_  Verdade, vou inicializar, acabei esquecendo. _3. Use main() sempre como a primeira função de seu programa. Assim você ajuda outros e a você mesmo a entender seu programa._ Certo, vou fazer na próxima. Em relação ao programa eu vou utilizar um valor já pré-definido mesmo para as notas. Agradeço a  explicação.

Comment: Veja aqueles programas nos links de que falei e compare a maneira de criar os blocos de memória no seu caso. Provavelmente o que quer é a opção mais flexível, usar um vetor de estruturas, e deve seguir como está lá. Se precisar posso alterar um exemplo quando der tempo aqui

Comment: Sim dei uma olhada, se puder acrescentar um exemplo do meu caso pode ser, mas por enquanto fiz assim mesmo: `struct Aluno { int matricula; int nota[3]; };`

Comment: Não se esqueça que com o cadastro e a mesma coisa. Talvez ache mais simples criar uma estrutura cadastro. Afinal o modelo é assim: o cadastro tem alunos que tem notas