# Tenho problemas em imprimir a saída de uma matriz de strings

Tags: c, array, matriz

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, k;
    char nomes[10][99];

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        printf("\nTurma %d:\n", j+1);
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("Aluno: ");
            scanf("%s", &nomes[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nTurma 1:\tTurma 2:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%s\t", &nomes[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

A saída da segunda coluna é perfeita (na medida do possível), porém a primeira coluna imprime apenas a primeira letra da string e concatena com a string respectiva da segunda coluna. Não entendo por que isso acontece, queria saber qual parte do código causa esse problema. Vou *linkar* uma imagem da entrada e uma da saída do programa para deixar tudo mais claro.

[image: entrada]

[image: saída]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O maior problema é que não está reservado espaço para a *string*, só para a matriz, então corrompe toda memória.

Coloquei uma constante para facilitar já que provavelmente quer mudar o tamanho das turmas e alunos e o valor é usado em vários lugares. Estou evitando [número mágico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101), embora deixei no tamanho no nome do aluno.

O número do tamanho reservado não bate com o do laço, então está bem errado, mas parece que está invertido em relação ao que deseja, só aumenta o problema já citado antes, a memória é todo corrompida.

Também protegi a entrada do nome do aluno com o tamanho máximo permitido.

O certo mesmo seria imprimir o cabeçalho das turmas em um laço, deixei isso para fazer.

O alinhamento tem algumas soluções possível, a que eu pensei ser mais fácil foi usar o formatador que indica o tamanho que deve ocupar. Deve ter jeito melhor, mas o que eu pensei agora foi fazer uma exceção para a primeira coluna para não ter o espaçamento. Depois talvez eu veja como deixar mais linear.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TURMAS 2
#define ALUNOS 10

int main() {
    char nomes[ALUNOS][TURMAS][31];
    for (int j = 0; j < TURMAS; j++) {
        printf("\nTurma %d:\n", j + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < ALUNOS; i++) {
            printf("Aluno: ");
            scanf("%30s", nomes[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nTurma 1:                      Turma 2:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ALUNOS; i++) {
        printf("%s", nomes[i][0]);
        for (int j = 1; j < TURMAS; j++) printf("%30s", nomes[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TcWFbC). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/zfcjxddv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/StringMatrix2.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Eu sou novo em C e não conheço muito, me ajudou demais :).