# Tabelas com nomes não convencionais como ABC1234

Tags: banco-de-dados, estilo-de-codificação, tabela-banco-de-dados, convenções-de-nome, erp

Tenho visto alguns que alguns sistemas adotam uma forma diferente de nomear tabelas com letras e números como `ABC1234, XX_900`, etc.

Estes dias estive trabalhando na criação de algumas consultas em um sistema que adota este tipo de abordagem, mais do que `1200 tabelas` para percorrer para descobrir onde estava os dados de uma determinada tabela (`Produtos`).

Felizmente, encontrei algumas consultas que deixaram a tarefa menos dolorosa, como por exemplo, pesquisar em todas as tabelas pelo nome da coluna `Produto`,

```
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName',
            t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%produto%'
ORDER BY    TableName,
            ColumnName
```

Mesmo assim o número de tabelas retornados foi assustador, mais de 200!

Então a questão é:

**Qual a vantagem deste tipo de adotar este tipo de nomenclatura para as tabelas? Seria apenas para dificultar a vida de pessoas 'estranhas' ao projeto?**

Comment: Acho difícil responder essa perguntar sem  ser muito subjetiva. A única vantagem ao meu ver é que você escreve menos quando os nomes das tabelas são abreviados. Uma possibilidade é que elas tenham sido criadas de forma automatizada, por isso os nomes esquisitos. O que eu recomendo pra te ajudar é criar views para as consultas e aí utilizar nomes significativos. Assim você só precisaria consultar as views, o que tornaria as consultas bem mais legíveis.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @GiulianaBezerra

Comment: Relacionado: http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Nonsense_naming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esta era uma técnica usada nos anos 70, havia um limite de caracteres possíveis e dar nomes significativos não era prioridade, era melhor usar códigos. Tinha algum sentido naquela época, mas não muito. Na verdade acho que as pessoas imaginaram que teriam milhares de tabelas um dia e que a restrição do tamanho do nome iria continuar, o que foi uma ingenuidade.

Quem fez isso naquela época poderia ter mudado o padrão pelo menos em coisas novas. Por alguma razão acham que manter o padrão compensa mais. Não vejo vantagem.

Há quem nunca precisou fazer isso, mas viu que alguém fazia e achou que era interessante. É o que eu falo sempre, as pessoas seguem regras sem saber o porquê. Provavelmente foi algo do tipo "uma grande empresa fez assim, deve ser uma boa prática, vou fazer igual".

ERPs grandes costumam ter muitas tabelas mesmo, milhares. Não sei se todas são realmente necessárias, mas atender bem necessidades amplas horizontal e verticalmente exige isso tudo.

Eu fui desenvolvedor de um sistema assim e era terrível. Pior, foi criado nos anos 90 e já na época tinha técnicas melhores que isso, mas não usaram porque alguém quem tinha poder decisão aprendeu fazer assim e impôs essa desgraça para o que hoje são muitos milhares de desenvolvedores lidando com essa dificuldade.

Mas pra ser justo, passado um tempo você acostuma com os nomes :D E a complicação maior nem está no nome. A estrutura dessas tabelas e seus relacionamentos costumam ser pavorosos. Imagine um monte de gente, cada um com seu *bias*, sem entendimento do todo e do que já existe, criando coisas diferentes em algo monolítico com prazos pesando mais que qualidade.

Tem muita coisa, muita mesmo que as pessoas fazem hoje porque todo mundo sempre fez assim, mas faziam assim porque há 50 anos era obrigado, hoje não é mais. [Comentários por exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15566/101).

Hoje a vantagem é zero.

Comment: `"uma grande empresa fez assim, deve ser uma boa prática, vou fazer igual"` Verdade.

Comment: "*uma grande empresa empresa fez assim, deve ser uma boa prática, vou fazer igual*" - Eu poderia até dar nomes aos bois em muitos casos, pois em alguns segundos já pensei em umas 5 grandes fábricas de bugs que se autodenominam fábricas de software, todas multinacionais. :)