# Dúvida sobre valores em matriz

Tags: c, loop, matriz, array, lógica

> Um bom exemplo de conjunto de dados é a reserva de passagens de um voo. Construir um programa em C para reserva de passagens de avião. O avião possui 50 fileiras com 6 assentos cada. O programa deverá possuir:
>
> - Dois vetores cuja quantidade de posições é o número total de assentos do avião.
> - Em um vetor será cadastrado o nome do passageiro de cada assento e no outro, o número do assento.
> - Uma matriz para representar cada assento. Se o assento estiver ocupado, será armazenado na posição da matriz o valor 1 (um). Se o assento estiver livre, será armazenado na matriz o valor 0 (zero).
>
> Inicializar todas as posições da matriz com o valor 0 (zero ).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


main () {


int assentos[300] ; //Vetor com número de assentos
char nomes[300][15] ; //Matriz para os nomes de cada passageiro 

int contadorAssentos = 0 ; //Variável de acesso ao índice do vetor assentos
int contadorNomes = 0 ; //Variável de acesso a matriz nomes 

int ocupados[50][6]  ;  //Matriz para cada assento
char escolha ; //Variável de escolha para prosseguir com o programa ou não
int i,j ; //Variável de controle da matriz de assentos



// Preenchendo e imprimindo a matriz de assentos ocupados ou não com zero para verificação
for ( i = 0 ; i <= 49; i++)  {


            for (j = 0 ; j <= 5 ; j++) {


                        ocupados[i][j] = 0 ;

                        printf ("%d", ocupados[i][j]) ;

                        }
    printf ("\n");
}



//Fim loop de preenchimento



//Inicia programa
do { 



printf ("\nDigite o nome do passageiro : ") ;
scanf("%s", &nomes[contadorNomes])  ;

printf("\nDigite o numero do assento requerido : ");
scanf("%d", &assentos[contadorAssentos]) ;




printf("\nNome do passageiro :  %s", nomes[contadorNomes]) ;


printf("\nAssento escolhido : %d",assentos[contadorAssentos]) ;



contadorAssentos ++ ;
contadorNomes ++ ;


printf("\n\nDeseja continuar ? <S/N>") ;
scanf(" %c", &escolha) ;




}

while ((escolha == 'S')|| (escolha == 's')) ;


}
```

O que seria mais recomendado para percorrer a matriz e atribuir o valor 1 exatamente a posição informada na variável assento? Como chegar exatamente em cada posição?

Penso que utilizaria um `for` para percorrer, porém não consigo implementar ainda uma maneira de relacionar o número do assento com a posição na matriz.

Comment: Basta matemática, a não ser que eu não tenha entendido.

Comment: Boa noite, obrigado por responder !

Bom, eu entendi que poderia percorrer o array e jogar na posição específica com o for..porém a minha dúvida é como montar uma lógica com esse for para transformar a posição do assento informada em posição na matriz..

Por exemplo...se o usuário informar o assento 200, teria que percorrer o array e passar as coordenadas de linhas e colunas..mas a minha dúvida é justamente porque o usuário vai informar somente um parâmetro, que é o número armazenado no vetor, e para acessar a matriz teria que usar dois. [i][j]..pode realmente ser matemática, to tentando

Comment: Aí você calcula a posição em vez de percorrer alguma coisa, é divisão e subtração, acho que uma mutiplicação também.

Comment: Entendi...muito obrigado amigo..vou tentar aqui =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código está um pouco desorganizado, faz algumas coisas desnecessárias como fazer laço para zerar a matriz, tem variável desnecessária, mas falta encerrar quando esgota o número de assentos, informar que o assento já está ocupado e obviamente ocupar o assento, além de não mostrar um mapa (ok, o exercício não pede, mas é o jeito de ver se ficou tudo certo).

Para saber a fileira é fácil, basta dividir por 6. Tem que subtrair 1 porque o *array* começa em 0. O arredondamento do inteiro garantirá que o número é redondo. se dividir 9 por 6 dará 1 (seria 1,5, mas um `int` não tem casas decimais).

Eu fiz como estava, mas acho que seria melhor não perguntar se quer continuar, se o assento fosse o 0, poderia terminar.

O cálculo do assento é um pouco mais complicado, mas não muito. Faz a mesma conta e depois multiplica por 6 novamente para obter a posição do assento como se não tivesse fileiras. Pega o número do assento e subtrai da posição encontrada na conta anterior, aí você acha o deslocamento do assento.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int assentos[300];
    char nomes[300][15];
    int ocupados[50][6] = { 0 };
    int contadorAssentos = 0;
    char escolha;
    do { 
        printf("\nDigite o nome do passageiro: ");
        scanf("%s", nomes[contadorAssentos]);
        printf("\nDigite o numero do assento requerido: ");
        scanf("%d", &assentos[contadorAssentos]);
        printf("\nNome do passageiro: %s", nomes[contadorAssentos]);
        printf("\nAssento escolhido: %d", assentos[contadorAssentos]);
        int fileira = (assentos[contadorAssentos] - 1) / 6;
        int assento = assentos[contadorAssentos] - 1 - fileira * 6;
        if (ocupados[fileira][assento]) printf("\nO assento já está ocupado, escolha outro!");
        ocupados[fileira][assento] = 1;
        if (contadorAssentos++ == 300) break;
        printf("\nDeseja continuar? <S/N>");
        scanf(" %c", &escolha);
    } while (escolha == 'S' || escolha == 's');
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) printf("F%02dA%d=%s | ", i + 1, j + 1, ocupados[i][j] ? "ocupado" : "livre  ");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EUoJSl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hyvdxfpk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/PlaneOcupation.c).

Comment: Bigown....muito obrigado ! 

Já percebi que o seu código tem dicas valiosas..vou tentar entender linha por linha pra pegar a lógica utilizada...acredito que seja o mais importante né...vou tentar tirar as conclusões comentando o código e posto aqui para conferir, se for possível

Comment: @Edsts Sim, se fizer isto estará à frente de muita gente. O que a gente mais vê o aprendiz de programador achar que já sabe tudo e não precisa melhorar olhando como os mais experientes fazem. Não que o meu jeito seja o único bom, é interessante ver vários estilos para forma o seu. Comentários didáticos ok, mas não cai no conto do "comentar tudo": http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15566/101. Acabei de ver um erro no meu código, esqueci uma linha, conserto depois.

Comment: Compreendo perfeitamente. Eu sou estudante de análise de sistemas, 2º período apenas. De certa forma eu vejo que tem alunos da minha turma que sabem menos que eu, mas eu sempre digo que o que sei é MUITO pequeno e básico..prova disso foi o código que postei agora, cheio de problemas. Estou na fase de aprendizagem inicial, sei que é uma estrada infinita, pois sempre podemos aprender e melhorar mais. Tenho mantido contato com amigos desenvolvedores mais experientes e tenho conseguido dicas boas também...acredito que preciso antes de mais nada aprimorar a lógica de programação prioritariamente

Comment: E sobre os comentários, também agradeço pela dica, pois vejo muita gente de fato replicando que quanto mais comentar, melhor..como não tenho muita experiência, meio que tinha tendência a seguir isso, mas com um pouquinho de desconfiança também...pois deve ser estranho pra passar um código legado todo embaralhado né

Comment: Você fez o certo que é dar nomes bons para as variáveis, isso elimina muito a necessidade de comentário. Os nomes poderiam ser melhores, mas esses demonstram bem o que está ocorrendo. Em C de fato alguns comentários são bons porque não é a linguagem mais legível do mundo.

Comment: Certo, nisso sempre tento dar nomes fáceis pra facilitar a compreensão                        Agora, sobre o código : int ocupados[50][6] = { 0 }; -> Aqui entendi que para inicializar uma matriz com um único valor igual, basta por entre chaves desta maneira né                         int contadorAssentos = 0; -> Aqui reparei que utilizou somente uma variável de acesso aos índices e tirou a outra...então posso concluir que posso tratar acesso aos índices de vários arrays com uma única variável de controle, certo ?                             (perguntarei mais depois dessas)

Comment: Ficou mal organizado..melhor eu responder a minha pergunta com o que vou perguntar ?

Comment: @Edsts Se são outros problemas seria melhor fazer outra pergunta. Essa inicialização só funciona para o 0. O valor que vai no índice não tem qualquer vinculação com nada, pode ser um literal ou uma variável qualquer, pode ser até uma expressão que calcula seu valor, o que importa é que tenha o número certo lá no momento certo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, bigown...estou tentando desenvolver o exercício com a minha maneira, aproveitando as dicas de lógica que me deixou..muito grato !