# Qual significado de branch, tag e trunk?

Tags: terminologia, svn

O que significam e quais as melhores práticas para usá-los?

Comment: Apesar de ser considerada um pouco ampla, acho esta pergunta extremamente pertinente, e é dúvida de várias pessoas iniciando no desenvolvimento de projetos com versionamento. +1

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## [*Trunk*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout)

É o principal tronco de desenvolvimento, seguindo desde o início do projeto até o presente. É nele que o projeto deve se basear sempre. Normalmente é gerido por um desenvolvedor e recebe *merges* após aprovação de alguém que é responsável pelo projeto. Não faz sentido existir mais do que um *trunk*.

## [*Branch*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.whatis.html)

É um galho da árvore de desenvolvimento. É uma cópia do código derivado de um certo ponto do *trunk* que é utilizado para a aplicação de mudanças no código, preservando a integridade do código no *trunk*. Se as mudanças funcionam de acordo com o planejado, elas geralmente são mescladas de volta para o tronco principal (*trunk*). É muito usado para experimentos e para desenvolvimentos paralelos.

É usado o tempo todo. Apesar do *trunk* ser o repositório principal, todo o desenvolvimento costuma ser feito em cima dos galhos locais ou remotos dependendo do fluxo de trabalho escolhido. É comum chamarmos o *branch* de versão de trabalho. É um rascunho que pode ser guardado para depois, para jogar fora, permanecer privado para um desenvolvedor ou grupo específico sem entrar no projeto.

Onde existem muitos *branches* pode criar dificuldades para executar o *merge*, por isso cada vez mais sistemas de controle de versão distribuídos estão fazendo cada vez mais sucesso em projetos muito ativos e principalmente descentralizados. Por isso é comum não incentivar *branches* descontroladamente quando se usa SVN.

Em muitos casos o *branch* funciona como uma futura versão.

## [*Tag*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.tags.html)

É um marcador de um estado do código em um determinado momento. É um ponto no tempo no *trunk* ou em um *branch* que você deseja preservar. As duas principais razões para a preservação seriam:

- este é um grande lançamento do software, se alfa, beta, RC ou RTM;
- este é o ponto mais estável do software antes de aplicar revisões importantes sobre o *trunk*.

Não é comum trabalhar em cima de uma *tag*. É criado um marco que pode ser acessado facilmente. Quando encontrar um *bug* em versão antiga que precisa de uma solução, é fácil criar um *branch* em cima dele para fazer o conserto.

O que costuma diferenciar *tag* de *branch* é justamente a estabilidade do conteúdo. Você não deve deveria mexer em um repositório *tag*. Ele se diferencia do *trunk* por ser algo secundário e quase sempre está no passado.

## Como usar

Em projetos de código aberto, os *branches* que não são aceitos no *trunk* pelos participantes do projeto podem se tornar as bases para *forks*, por exemplo.

[*Fork*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development)) costuma ser um repositório completamente novo, com seu próprio *trunk* mas que é derivado de um repositório original (mesmo que este já seja um *fork*). É uma árvore de desenvolvimento nova mas criada de outra árvore. É comum haver comunicação entre estas árvores e em alguns casos até bidirecionalmente. Nestes casos o *trunk* de um acaba funcionando como *branch* de outro. Desta forma percebe-se que estes conceitos são bem abstratos.

Os conceitos apresentados são recomendações. Nada impede dos desenvolvedores fazerem de uma forma totalmente diferente se for mais adequado para o projeto. Esta é uma forma consagrada e provavelmente mais adequada para a maioria dos casos. Quanto menor a equipe e mais centralizado é o processo, menos vantagens existem em usar este esquema. E de fato é comum, mesmo em projetos *open source* pequenos, que o desenvolvimento acabe sendo feito essencialmente em cima do *trunk* e *forks* costumam funcionar como *branches* do projeto.

É preciso experimentar alguns fluxos de trabalho diferentes e escolher o que traz maior benefício para seu projeto.

[Ilustração da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion):

[image: Fluxo]

Baseada em [What do “branch”, “tag” and “trunk” mean in Subversion repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16163/221800) e outras respostas da página.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

### Trunk

Pasta principal, como numa árvore o tronco, nele fica o projeto que está estável e que servirá de base para novas *Branchs*.
Geralmente contém os arquivos mais atuais do projeto, bem como as correções de bugs e os últimos recursos adicionados ao projeto.

### Branch

Um ramo digamos do projeto, uma divisão do projeto se baseando na principal porém que esteja seguindo linhas de pensamento diferentes Ex: Correção de bugs de uma versão que está online estaria em uma *Branch*, a atualização ou criação de um outro layout estaria em outra *Branch* e a criação de alguma nova funcionalidade poderia estar eu outra *Branch* diferente das anteriores

### Tag

Normalmente utilizada para lançamentos de “releases”, a tag marca um ponto estável do desenvolvimento.
A seguir um exemplo de utilização
Um projeto inicia e um repositório é criado. Ex.: meuprojeto 1.0.