# Como é o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação até lançamento de uma release com subversion?

Tags: versionamento, svn

Estava para criar uma pergunta dessa: **[O que "branch", "tag" e "trunk" realmente significam?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20989/o-que-branch-tag-e-trunk-realmente-significam)**

Li e ainda fiquei com dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento prático de ***branches*** e ***tags***.

Sobre a forma padrão/recomendada, ***branches*** é o início, de uma mudança em um código-fonte já existente, ou a criação de novos fontes em um projeto?

Em que momento exatamente é utilizado o ***tags***?

Peço, por gentileza, um exemplo escrito (claro, mas imagens também são bem vindas) de como seria o ciclo de vida de geração de uma nova versão de um software ou um pacote de softwares passando pelos ***branches***, ***merges*** e as ***tags***.

Comment: Conheço dois excelentes artigos (em inglês) sobre o assunto: [Source Control Done Right](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Source-Control-Done-Right.aspx) e [Release Management Done Right](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Release-Management-Done-Right.aspx) (o primeiro mais diretamente no assunto, o segundo menos, porém ainda bastante relevante). Se houver interesse, posso tentar formular uma resposta com base neles, mas já adianto que seria uma resposta "genérica" - já que não domino, ou sequer já usei, o SVN. Se ainda assim acharem que é pertinente, me falem que eu escrevo.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, com certeza! Ficaria muito grato! =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há duas principais maneiras de se utilizar o ***branch***, que chamarei de *"branching by rule"* (galhos criados por padrão) e *"branching by exception"* (galhos criados em condições excepcionais). Tocarei nesse assunto mais adiante, mas para simplificar a resposta assumirei a segunda estratégia - em que a maior parte do desenvolvimento ocorre no ***trunk*** e apenas ocasionalmente é feito um *branch*. Creio que essa estratégia seja mais aplicável à maioria dos projetos existentes, mas é apenas minha opinião.

### Um exemplo de fluxo de trabalho

Digamos que você e outros desenvolvedores iniciaram um projeto de software. Cada um escreve um pouco de código, faz *commit* no repositório principal, obtém o código dos outros usando *update*, etc, até que seu sistema esteja pronto para passar à fase de testes (ou QA, ou seja lá qual for a fase seguinte no seu fluxo de trabalho). A primeira coisa a fazer é **congelar** seu código no estado atual - não permitir mudanças no mesmo até que ele passe por **todas** as etapas de testes até ele estar pronto para a produção. Se algum erro for detectado numa dessas fases, não se deve alterar o código ali mesmo e seguir em frente; é importante que as alterações feitas pela equipe de desenvolvimento sejam novamente congeladas e comecem o ciclo todo de novo (caso contrário as mudanças podem introduzir novos bugs, que não serão detectados a menos que o código volte à equipe de testes).

Esse é o momento em que o uso de um ***tag*** se mostra útil: se você está planejando a versão `1.0`, e seu código - se aprovado - se tornará a versão `1.0`, você pode "etiquetar" a revisão atual como `1.0 RC1` por exemplo ("candidato 1 à liberação 1.0"). É essa revisão que a equipe de testes vai usar, é essa que a equipe de QA vai usar, é essa que a equipe de homologação/*staging* vai usar... e se todas aprovarem, é essa que vai pra produção. Se alguma dessas equipes vetar a revisão, os desenvolvedores corrigem os bugs, etiquetam a nova revisão como `1.0 RC2` e enviam para os testes. Eventualmente uma delas irá ser aprovada por todos, e essa mesma receberá *também* a etiqueta `1.0`.

[image: Diagrama 1]

Os desenvolvedores, é claro, já podem ir desenvolvendo a versão `1.1` (ou `2.0`) se quiserem - não precisam necessariamente esperar pela `1.0` ser aprovada. Mas se o candidato à liberação (*release*) for rejeitado, não seria uma boa ideia pegar o código do jeito que está - cheio de código que só iria ficar pronto na versão seguinte - e tentar acabá-lo às pressas para "encaixar" na versão `1.0`. Melhor seria interromper o que se está fazendo, pegar de volta o código com a etiqueta `1.0 RC1` e fazer as alterações necessárias a partir deste.

Esse é o momento em que se faz um ***branch*** - parte-se da revisão `1.0 RC1`, cria-se um novo *branch* para a versão `1.0` e começa-se a modificá-la. Faz-se quantos *commits* forem necessários nesse *branch*, até que se acredite que o código está estável o suficiente para se tornar o `1.0 RC2`. Quando isso finalmente for feito, envia-o aos testes e volta-se a trabalhar no *trunk* - talvez **mesclando** (*merge*) as correções feitas nesse *branch* ao código principal no *trunk* (pra não ter que repetir tudo lá). Se aplicável, é claro. O *branch* criado pode ser mantido - futuras modificações na versão `1.0` podem partir desse galho (uma vez que tudo o que é relativo às versões posteriores estarão no *trunk*).

[image: Diagrama 2]

Por fim, e se a versão `1.0` já estiver em produção e um novo bug surgir? Não seria bom simplesmente dizer "espere até a 1.1, daqui a umas 3 semanas ela vai estar pronta", o correto é providenciar uma `1.0.1` o mais rapidamente possível. Isso é feito da mesma forma descrita acima: pega-se o *branch* da `1.0` (nesse caso não é necessário se criar outro, pois a 1.0 está pronta, ela só vai receber correções de bug daqui pra frente), faz-se as mudanças necessárias nele e etiqueta-se como `1.0.1 RC1`. Faz-se uma `1.0.1 RC2` se necessário, da mesma forma que acima, até uma delas ser aprovada e virar a `1.0.1`. Novo bug? Segue-se para a `1.0.2 RC1`. E assim por diante.

[image: Diagrama 3]

### *Branching* por padrão

O fluxo descrito acima assume que todo o desenvolvimento "principal" será feito no *trunk* - o que muitas vezes é razoável, pois muitos projetos só são implantados em um só local (o servidor de sua empresa, por exemplo). Mas em outras é necessário se manter várias versões ao mesmo tempo, por exemplo quando se tem N clientes com seu sistema instalado e cada um deles possui uma versão específica - e sem condições de atualizar toda vez que uma versão nova surge.

Nesse caso, *pode ser* (mas não necessariamente é) melhor não fazer o desenvolvimento todo no *trunk*, em vez disso se criar um *branch* separado cada vez que uma versão nova for planejada. Às vezes é desejável fazer isso independentemente do cenário, já que se pode planejar e ir desenvolvendo várias versões simultaneamente, i.e. se você já sabe que provavelmente terá uma versão `1.1` *paralela* à `2.0`, fica difícil saber qual é o mais indicado pra ocupar o *trunk*, então que tal decidir por "nenhum deles" e dar a cada versão seu galho separado? Mesmo porque no primeiro bug que aparecesse você teria de fazer isso mesmo...

Se você optar por essa estratégia, então resta ainda a pergunta: o que colocar no *trunk*? Eu diria que seu papel é armazenar a "última" revisão do código, aquela que "irá pra frente" quando novas versões forem planejadas e implementadas. Ou seja, se a `1.0` está em funcionamento, você decidiu acrescentar uma `1.1` para disponibilizar de imediato uma funcionalidade bacana que você está implementando na `2.0`, mas isso que você fez na `1.1` é só provisória - não serve pra versão seguinte, pois você já refatorou tudo - então esse código não iria ser mesclado com o *trunk*. Já uma correção de bug, que potencialmente afete todas as suas versões ativas, essa tem que estar prontamente disponível para ser mesclada com todas as "pontas de revisões" (*tips* - não sei se o SVN usa essa terminologia) relevantes - justificando assim sua inclusão no *trunk*.

[image: Diagrama 4]

### Outras considerações

O uso que eu descrevi das *tags* é o mínimo necessário para uma gestão de liberações saudável - você pode criar **mais** etiquetas se quiser, por exemplo para denominar versões alfa e beta. Em suma, usa-se uma *tag* sempre que for interessante apresentar uma versão "congelada" do projeto a alguém (não no sentido que essa versão não será mexida, mas no sentido que sempre que alguém reportar um bug naquela versão você saiba *exatamente* em que estado seu código estava quando o problema foi identificado).

Quanto a "mudança em um código-fonte já existente, ou a criação de novos fontes em um projeto" isso não determina nem é determinado pelo uso de *branches*: se a mudança ou inclusão ocorrer durante o desenvolvimento principal, ela vai pro *trunk* como todo o resto; se a mudança ou inclusão ocorrer quando se está dando manutenção a uma versão já "finalizada" (i.e. em produção, ou em processo de homologação), ela vai pro *branch* daquela versão. Criando o *branch*, se ele ainda não existir (se o projeto correr excepcionalmente bem, com todos os bugs de uma versão resolvidos antes de se começar a desenvolver a próxima, então pode ser que jamais seja necessário criar um único *branch*).

> Essa resposta se baseou em grande parte nos artigos [***Release Management Done Right***](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Release-Management-Done-Right.aspx) ("Gestão de Liberações Feitas Corretamente") e [***Source Control Done Right***](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Source-Control-Done-Right.aspx) ("Controle de Versões Feito Corretamente"), contextualizando de acordo com o pedido na pergunta (os originais são muito abrangentes para serem totalmente cobertos aqui) e com minha experiência pessoal (os padrões de versionamento, por exemplo, são fictícios, e não correspondem necessariamente a nenhuma "boa prática de versionamento").

Comment: Agora acho que dá para montar uma estrutura para fazer uns testes!! =D Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Espero contribuir, na minha experiencia profissional o `trunk` sempre funcionou como uma versão que reflete o que esta em produção ou a versão que mais próximo dela esta, ou seja na maioria das vezes a versão garantida, aprovado e testada, ou a base do projeto dependendo é claro de como sua empresa utiliza.

Já as `Branches` são utilizadas para criar novas features, baseadas no trunk, com a finalidade de uma mudança em um código-fonte em relação ao trunk.

`Tags` são versões pacotes fechados do trunk ou seja você poderia ter uma versão 1.0 e outra 2.0, lançada com novos funcionalidades e manter as duas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Trunk: É onde fica o seu produto liberado, ou seja, tudo que está pronto para ir para o cliente.

Branch: Você abre uma nova branch para cada novo projeto de evolução/manutenção no seu código. Nela serão "copiados" os códigos da trunk para a branch onde você faz todas as alterações, testes e homologações necessários.
Ao final do projeto você faz um merge da branch para a trunk, onde o código é atualizado na trunk.
Com isso durante o andamento projeto você fica com seu código protegido das novas implementações. Então caso um cliente relate algum bug, você pode fazer a correção na trunk e enviar para ele sem preocupações.

Tag: É usada apenas como uma fácil marcação para o número da revisão do seu repositório onde o release do seu produto foi gerado. Geralmente eu crio uma pasta dentro da TAG com o nome "Produto V1.1.234". A geração dos pacotes releases são a partir desta pasta.
Isto garante que enquanto você está gerando algum release ninguém faz merge de algum projeto ou bug e atrapalha o seu produto homologado.