# Como funciona a nomenclatura de versão para projetos privados ou públicos?

Tags: git, versionamento

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que serve como *bootstrap* para futuras contribuições via Git, e gostaria de saber qual o esquema de versão mais utilizado, digo "versão" relativa ao estado que se encontra o software, exemplo

versão 0.1.1

Seguindo as diretrizes básicas de [software versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning), como escalar a versão de acordo com as contribuições?
Utilizando somente *branch's* e *tag's*? Ou existe outras boas práticas?

Comment: Você está procurando algo assim? http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ . Aqui tem mais detalhes: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow/. Se for, eu coloca uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: Obrigado @Dherik é exatamente esse o conceito que preciso para organizar o projeto, é mais o menos o que imaginava, mas precisava de um exemplo profissional. vlw

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 13):

Um modelo conhecido e que muitas empresas adotam é o [GitFlow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode notar, ele abrange grande parte dos aspectos do desenvolvimento de software: **tags** para marcar versões, uma branch da **versão estável** (master), branch de **desenvolvimento** (develop), branch das **atividades** (feature branches), branch para **correções** (hotfixes) e assim por diante.

Outro link que posso te indicar, que dá mais alguns detalhes de como este modelo funciona na prática, pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow/).

Embora este modelo pareça um pouco burocrático, ele ajuda a organizar o processo de desenvolvimento de software. Logicamente, você não é obrigado a adotar este modelo de forma rígida, podendo flexibilizá-lo de acordo com as necessidades do seu projeto.

Sobre o número das versões, como dito anteriormente, é usado as `tags` do Git para isto. Um exemplo, criando a versão 0.1:

```
git tag -a 0.1 -m "Versão 0.1, com melhorias na consulta de pessoas"
```

A nomenclatura da versão em si pode variar (0.1, v0.1, etc), mas perceba que ela sempre ocorre na branch `master`, que é para ser a branch estável do sistema neste modelo.

Se tiver dificuldades em seguir o modelo, a ferramenta [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) com o plugin do GitFlow poderá auxiliar você e sua equipe. Mas recomendo entender o modelo e não depender de ferramentas deste tipo no futuro. O ideal é cada membro da equipe sentir-se livre para usar a ferramenta que achar mais adequada.

Comment: Com certeza. Achei esse modelo o ideal e vou enxuga-lo de acordo com as necessidades do meu projeto. Só tenho uma questão básica, considerando a branch MASTER como a principal e também a branch que lanço as TAG's de versões, todas as sub releases que estão entre DEV e MASTER, serão mescladas a master por qualquer integrante? ou seria uma boa pratica fazer o **approval** dessas features na master através de pull request?

Comment: Fica a seu critério, mas acho o _pull request_ bem útil. 

No caso do `merge`  via _pull request_ das branches do tipo _feature_ para _develop_, elas podem ser realizadas por algum membro da equipe que não participou da atividade. É possível, inclusive, aproveitar esta etapa para fazer o _code review_ do código por quem vai fazer o **approval**. Lembrando que, no modelo proposto, as únicas branches que fazem merge direto com a master são as de release e hotfixes.

Comment: Show de bola, vou convecionar o **pull request** e por enquanto eu mesmo faço o papel do **approval**. Obrigado pela ajuda, irmão.

Answer (score 11):

Não dá para afirmar qual é o mais usado, e mesmo que desse isto não lhe serviria para nada.

Tem algumas diretrizes que podem ser adotadas dentro do que se usa, mas você pode escolher a melhor forma para o seu projeto. Se espera que outras pessoas contribuam talvez elas quererão influenciar nisto.

Comece fazer de um jeito, se não der certo, mude. Só a experiência pode determinar o melhor jeito para cada projeto.

Tem linguagens ou tecnologias que indicam uma forma de fazer.

Há uma [lista de formas diferentes no Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3199/389). Eu coloquei uma resposta com versionamento baseado em datas que pode ser útil em certos cenários e ela foi bem votada.

Se quiser saber sobre o [Semantic Version já tem uma pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51817/101). Ele parece estar sendo mais adotado agora. Mas como minha resposta lá indica, o ponto exato de troca é subjetivo. Só dá para determinar linhas gerais.

A página que você mencionou já dá outras formas e você pode pesquisar em projetos em repositórios públicos por outras formas.

Algumas pessoas gostam de por letras também. Ou números negativos mais raramente. Alguns usam números com algum significado específico.

Alguns usam o *hash* do *commit* que gerou uma *tag* no Git para ajudar localizar no repositório. Depende de como trabalha pode ser útil mas muitas vezes é redundante já que a *tag* deveria conter a informação da versão. Em alguns casos pode-se usar no *branch* também, mas é confuso. Em geral, [apenas *tags* deveriam ter versões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80583/101) ([mesmo no SVN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20989/101)). Exceção talvez quando o *branch* seja criado para organizar um *release* ou pelo menos *builds*.

Alguns preferem esquemas bem complicados. É válido, mas a não ser que tenha um bom motivo para isto, sugiro evitar. Quase sempre é uma complicação desnecessária e pouco ou nada vantajosa. O mesmo vale para trocas frequentes que fazem os números ficarem altos. Lembre-se que você vai falar, escrever e manipular muito esta designação. Facilite.

Se você quiser trocar a versão a hora que bem entender, pode e funciona. Só não vá criar versões novas decrementando números, aí gera confusão. O resto é gosto de adaptação ao fluxo que achar atender melhor a equipe.

Lembrando que você pode ter nomenclaturas diferentes para uso interno do projeto e para divulgação "comercial".

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: muito bom o seu comentário, com certeza vai me ajudar a aprimorar meu conhecimento e conseguir lançar esse projeto para que os outros integrantes possam contribuir de forma unificada.
Também prefiro trabalhar de forma livre (sem dependencias de tecnologia). Já arriquei a versionar um projeto pela HASH dos commits, mas acabou virando bolo de gato, não recomendo muito, a não ser que seja muito especifico mesmo. Obrigado irmão.

Answer (score 4):

Vou dar uma resposta baseada na proposta do site [SemVer.org](http://semver.org) (*semantic versioning*):

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> - MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> - MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> - PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
>
> Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

Tradução:

> Dado um número de versão no padrão MAIOR.MENOR.PATCH, incremente:
>
> - a MAIOR versão quando você introduz alterações incompatíveis na API,
> - a MENOR versão quando você adiciona funcionalidade de uma forma compatível com o que já existia (*backwards-compatible*), e
> - a versão do PATCH, quando você introduz correções compatíveis com o que já existia.
>
> Etiquetas adicionais para informações de pré-release e dados de build estão disponíveis como extensões ao formato MAIOR.MENOR.PATCH.