# O que é "build" e qual é a sua relação com a IDE?

Tags: terminologia, compilação, ide

Na área de desenvolvimento de software tem um termo que aparece com muita frequência que é o **build**. Ele sempre me surgi quando eu leio a respeito do Android Studio e outras ferramentas de desenvolvimento (geralmente IDEs), creio que ele deve fazer parte deste conceito (posso estar errado a respeito disso).

Eu gostaria de saber o que é **build** e qual é a relação que ele tem com a IDE?

Comment: É a regra básica do GoHorse, se compilar não precisa testar mais nada, significa que tá tudo certo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

É uma [conferência da Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_(developer_conference))... mentira :P Digo isto porque há muitos contextos possíveis, há dois mais usados que parecem ser do que está falando na pergunta

Ele não tem nada de muito especial, é o que a tradução diz mesmo, é a construção da aplicação, no sentido de gerar o executável final.

Por construção entenda que fará a compilação, *linkedição* e qualquer passo necessário para que a aplicação fique em estado que possa ser executado. Normalmente leva em consideração as dependências e evita refazer o que pode ser reaproveitado.

- Um *build* ocorre toda vez que precisa executar uma nova versão do código (não confundir com versão do projeto). Você manda fazê-lo, ele gera o executável e você já pode testar o que acabou de fazer. Há um software *builder* que cuida de fazer tudo certo dentro de certos critérios. Ele pode ser configurado por um IDE ou na mão (texto puro, XML, etc.). É algo que o desenvolvedor faz o tempo todo na sua máquina. Não mexe em numeração de versão.
- Há o *build* "oficial" que é gerado de tempo em tempo e que pode ser disponibilizado para algumas pessoas. Um deles eventualmente será liberado para o público ([versão do projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82369/101)). Nos esquemas de versionamento que o número do *build* é usado ele é incrementado sempre que um novo é criado.

  Não costuma ocorrer em linguagens interpretadas.

  O processo de testes, análises mais profundas e até o empacotamento pode ser feito junto. Esse é um processo maior. São considerados *builds* automatizados. No passado se costumava usar "compilar", mas não era semanticamente correto e passou-se usar o o termo "construir".

  É mais comum ser feito em um servidor dedicado com o código *commitado* por todos e gera algo para ser consumido por equipes de teste e até mesmo ser lançado como algo oficial. É comum ter um ou dois por dia, em casos extremos pode ter vários. Claro que depende do tamanho da equipe, da organização necessária. Alguns casos isso é levado ao extremo e recebe o nome de [*continuous integration*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), aí o *build* é parte do processo.

  Algumas tecnologias tem um processo bem próprio e passos específicos.

O termo pode ser usado em outros contextos de forma bem diferente, alguns bem específicos ou até algo geral como dizer *build* no lugar de *develop*.

## IDE

A princípio não tem nada a ver com IDE. Claro que todo IDE dispara a execução do *build* da aplicação para você por um *click* (provavelmente em menu) ou atalho. Eventualmente algum IDE tenha um mecanismo próprio de *build*, mas não é muito comum, até porque ele costuma ser necessário fora do IDE e não tem porque ter mecanismos diferentes, o IDE chama o que já existe externamente (por linha de comando ou outra integração, pode até ser disponível em biblioteca).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

**O que é?**

**Build**, no contexto do desenvolvimento de software, é uma versão "compilada" de um software ou parte dele que contém um conjunto de recursos que poderão integrar o produto final.

**Relação com as IDEs**

A relação é que algumas IDEs possuem um mecanismo de build. Falando de algumas linguagens, existem milhares de ferramentas de build, sendo a mais conhecida o `make`, muito usado para construir e executar tarefas de projetos escritos em `C` e `C++`, mas que para `Java`, por exemplo, possui muitas desvantagens e não é utilizado. As ferramentas mais conhecidas do `Java` possuem suporte das IDEs, e são facilmente executadas em qualquer sistema operacional.

Answer (score 1):

[Building](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/research/graphics/resources/vs_getting_started/vs_getting_started.htm) é o processo de transformar seus arquivos de texto de código-fonte em um ou mais arquivos chamados *alvos* que são usados quando o aplicativo é executado. Os projetos tem um único alvo: um arquivo executável (.exe), produzida pelo compilador os arquivos de origem em objeto intermediário (obj) arquivos que são, então, ligados a vários arquivos de biblioteca (.lib) e DLLs do Windows executável nativo.

Construir o executável com o Visual Studio é diferente do UNIX em que você nunca executar explicitamente um compilador, vinculador, ou outras ferramentas. Em vez disso eles são executados conforme a necessidade do Visual Studio para criar o arquivo .exe nativo destino do Windows. Você pode pensar nisso como o Visual Studio em tempo de compilação executando um "make" arquivo implícita determinado pelo seu tipo de projeto, seus arquivos de origem e outros itens, e suas dependências em outros projetos e bibliotecas.

O menu de configuração.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Build** compilar e ligar apenas os arquivos de origem que foram alterados desde a última compilação, enquanto Rebuild compilar e ligar todos os arquivos de origem, independentemente de terem sido alterados ou não. Build é a coisa normal para fazer e é mais rápido. Às vezes, as versões dos componentes alvo do projeto pode ficar fora de sincronia e um Rebuild é necessário para fazer a compilação bem-sucedida. Na prática, você nunca precisa de limpar.

**Build ou Rebuild** constrói ou reconstrói todos os projetos na sua solução Para definir o projeto de inicialização, clique direito sobre o nome do projeto desejado na aba Solution Explorer e selecione Definir como projeto de inicialização. O nome do projeto agora aparece em negrito. Uma vez que as soluções de casa normalmente têm apenas um projeto, construir ou reconstruir Solution é efetivamente o mesmo que construir ou reconstruir.

**Compile** apenas compila o arquivo de origem atual a ser editado. Útil para verificar rapidamente para erros quando o resto de seus arquivos de origem estão em um estado incompleto que impeça uma compilação de sucesso de todo o projeto. Ctrl-F7 é a tecla de atalho para compilar.