# Erros indevidos no Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Uso Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web.

Não sei muito sobre ele, fui aprendendo na prática.

Ele indica muitos erros como se minha classe não tivesse determinado atributo.

Notei que isso acontece principalmente quando altera uma classe colocando mais algum atributo. O novo atributo parece não ser interpretado.

E veja bem, se eu mandar fazer um Build, não dá erro nenhum, o projeto é compilado na totalidade. Posso executar e nada de errado acontecerá.

Minutos depois, na Error List começam a aparecer erros indicando que aqueles atributos novos não fazem parte da classe tal. E na tela, na View em que foi usado aquele atributo, ou no Controller, ele aparece sublinhado indicando um possível erro.

Agora um exemplo: Esta é minha classe:

```
public class ContaAReceber 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TipoReceitaID { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoReceita  TipoReceita { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CentroCustoID { get; set; }
    public virtual CentroCusto  CentroCusto { get; set; }

    public int? HonorarioID { get; set; }        
}
```

Na classe pode ser visto que existe um atributo HonorarioID.

Agora vejam a imagem do meu VC mostrando como se não houvesse esse atributo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

é como se o VS tivesse gravado e compilado a classe em sua forma inicial e não a renovasse.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que está acontecendo e como faço para isso parar.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Poste alguns código (os atributos destas classes) e imagens  de forma que ilustre o problema. Sobre [build](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157135/o-que-%C3%A9-build-e-qual-%C3%A9-a-sua-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-a-ide/157142#157142)

Comment: O que é `ContasAReceberDAO`? Aparentemente é Entity Framework, certo?

Comment: Sim, é EF, ContasAReceberDAO é uma classe que faz pequenas operações de gravação em banco. Mas não vem ao caso. Se eu coloco um método qualquer em uma classe, o compilo, e mais tarde altero, por exemplo, os parâmetros. Ele apresenta um erro dizendo que não há Overload com os parâmetros novos. E isto em mais de 30 classes. Não é o caso de uma delas.

Comment: É como se o VS compilasse a classe com os parâmetros originais e não aceitasse mais mudar e compilar novamente.

Comment: Algum motivo especial pra usar uma versão tão antiga do VS? Talvez valha mais a pena instalar a nova que tentar resolver os problemas nessa antiga: [Visual Studio 2017 CommunityEdition](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15)