# Qual a diferença entre build e linkagem?

Tags: compilação, build, linkagem

Já vi algumas representações em que o *build* está no mesmo lugar de quando acontece a *linkagem*, os dois são a mesma coisa?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Não são o mesmo. A [*linkagem*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101) é um dos passos que o [*build*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157135/101) realiza. O *build* pode realizar muitas coisas, até construir a aplicação ou solução completa, alguns desses passos que nem são parte do processo de criação do executável, mas certamente gerar o executável é o mais importante.

Em geral você tem pelo dois passos muito claros: a [compilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101) básica; a *linkagem*.

Mas algumas tecnologias podem não ser bem assim, ou por serem interpretadas ou a *linkagem* não conseguir ser dissociada da compilação, ainda que internamente sejam distintas.

O termo desta forma é mais usado em linguagens que são usadas de forma mais direta e clássica como C, C++ ou Rust.