# Duvida em utilização de git

Tags: git

Estamos migrando nosso controle de versão do Subversion para Git.

Estou encontrando o seguinte problema, temos um projeto grande com vários desenvolvedores, nosso fluxo utiliza as *branches*: **Master**, **Develop** e **Feature**.

Quando temos que fazer uma nova customização é criada uma nova *branch* **Feature** baseada na **Develop** e é desenvolvida a customização, porém quando um outro desenvolvedor tem que fazer outra customização ele segue o mesmo passo, criada uma outra *branch* **Feature** baseada na **Develop**.

Quando o desenvolvedor termina a customização é feito um *merge* entre as *branches* **Feature** e a **Develop** e é liberada para usuário fazer validação.

O problema é que como as duas *features* estão na *branch* **Develop**  quando for migrar para a **Master** gostaria de levar apenas uma *feature* e não a **Develop** inteira.

Gostaria de saber se o nosso fluxo está errado, se é assim que vocês trabalham com o Git.

Comment: **Relacionados:** [Como funciona a nomenclatura de versão para projetos privados ou públicos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82366/3635), [Qual é a diferença entre um branch e uma tag?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80583/3635) e [Quando incrementar a versão usando Semantic Versioning?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51817/3635)

Answer (score 4):

O melhor tutorial de git WorkFlow que eu já li: [Comparing Workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha opinião está faltando duas Branch importantes no projeto de vocês: **Release e a HotFix**

Answer (score 2):

Começa sempre novos branches de `master`. Até um ramo `dev`, `feature` ou `patch` estar no `master` muito pode acontecer. Os commits podem mudar, pode haver commits do ramos `dev` que afinal já não vão ser usados, alguém pode fazer uma force push e estragar a história dos commits ficando duplicados com hashes diferentes, etc.

O que está no `master` é garantido (e comum a todos os ramos/branches), o que vier de novo deve receber um rebase (para os commits ficarem re-ordenados) e depois entrar para o `master`.

É bom separar conceitos e pensar/decidir o que cada ramo faz. Ter um ramo dev durante meses onde tudo vai parar e só depois fazer merge no master costuma gerar problemas. Ciclos de iteração curtos é o melhor. Isso quer dizer que nem sempre o ramos dev está ativo.

Um modelo testado e que uso é:

- **patch branch**: 1 a 5 commits, alguma correção urgente
- **feature branch**: 1 a 50 commits (mais que isso deve talvez deva partido em partes)
- **dev branch**: 1 a 30 commits, para ir gerindo problemas não urgentes e backlog, sempre tentando não pressionar mais coisas que o necessário

Todos os 3 ramos fazem `merge` diretamente no `master` quando estiverem prontos, e nesse momento os outros ramos que estejam ativos fazem um `rebase` ao `master` para importar os commits que entraram para o `master`.

Answer (score 2):

Na minha experiência, a primeira coisa que você precisa definir antes de escolher um Workflow para o `git` é qual o seu **ciclo de releases**.

O melhor modelo pro seu caso depende de uma variável principal:

> O código que está em produção é continuamente alterado com novas
>   features assim que ficam prontas (rolling release), ou existe uma
>   prática de incorporar todas as novas features e bugfixes em um pacote
>   fechado e liberar esse para produção (fixed release)?

---

Note que em ambos os casos é crucial que **os novos branches sejam criados a partir do branch onde vão ser incorporados** ao final do processo. Sem intermediários.

---

**Rolling releases**

Esse modelo fácilita usar um fluxo menos estruturado como o [Github Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/).

Tendo 2 branches principais `master` e `develop`, todas as features são baseadas em `master`. Quanto estão prontas elas são incorporadas em `develop` para homologação, e após a liberação **a feature** é incorporada em `master` e liberada para produção.

Nesse modelo `develop` **nunca é incorporado em** `master` e frequentemente você deleta `develop` e recria a partir de `master` quando esse branch fica "sujo" com alterações que nunca foram aprovadas e não serão incorporadas. Muitas empresas preferem chamar o `develop` de `staging` nesse caso, pra evitar confusão.

**Fixed releases**

Nesse caso um processo mais estruturado vale a pena, como o [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), ilustrado na resposta do Diogo.

Nesse processo, os branches principais `master` e `develop` servem a propósitos diferentes do fluxo anterior. `master` é o que você está rodando agora, e `develop` **é o seu próximo release completo**, ou seja, você sabe que aquele código é estável e está só esperando finalizar o ciclo para incorporar **todo** o `develop` em `master`. Nesse caso então faz sentido que novos branches sejam criados a partir de `develop` para que os desenvolvedores trabalhem no código estável *mais atual*.

Nesse processo você frequentemente tem outros branches para teste, por exemplo um `staging` onde acontece o teste antes da feature ir para `develop` e o importante é que, no princípio de cada ciclo, `develop` e `master` sejam rigorosamente iguais.