# O que essas palavras significam no Git/GitHub: fork, clone, track?

Tags: git, github

Tem pouco tempo que comecei usar Git e até essa semana eu só usei pela interface do Visual Studio. Após diversos problemas com o Git pela interface, eu comecei resolver algumas coisas pelo console, então agora estou realmente tendo que aprender Git.
Eu acho diversas fontes me falando comandos para resolver meus problemas, mas poucos lugares realmente explicam esse termos que vejo em todos lugares.

Comment: Acho que já foi respondida aqui, se conseguir localizar, colo o link dela.

Comment: Relacionada: [O que “branch”, “tag” e “trunk” realmente significam?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20989/o-que-branch-tag-e-trunk-realmente-significam/20996#20996)

Comment: `Fork` é uma caracteristica do Git?

Comment: @diegofm a outra pergunta é sobre SVN. Esses termos são genéricos para todos sistemas de versionamento? Além disso ele não explica `fork` e `track`. Apesar que também não tenho certeza se isso é do Git ou só GitHub.

Comment: Pela definição que eu li nas perguntas de Git e essa de SVN, têm o mesmo significado sim, então tirei da minha pergunta.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Repositório**

Repositório é o local aonde ficam os seus arquivos com os commits, branchs, etc. Tudo o que for referente ao git ficará nessa pasta, geralmente chamada **.git** que é o repositório.

**Fork**

Explicando com minhas palavras, seria como se fosse uma curva que você faz e pega os arquivos para edita-lós e depois subir no repositório. No Github quando você clica em **fork** no repositório de alguém, ele pega o repositório completo dessa pessoa e copia para sua conta git, lá você poderá editar esses arquivos e depois devolver a essa pessoa com as suas edições, se a pessoa aceitar, suas alterações também entram no repositório dele.

**Branch**

É ramificações que você faz para quando tiver desenvolvendo novas funcionalidades. Quando você inicia o **git init** você tem um branch padrão que é o **master**. Quando tiver trabalhando em equipe evite desenvolver no branch **master** pois poderá dar muitos conflitos. Sempre crie um branch para fazer suas modificações. Por exemplo, você vai desenvolver uma funcionalidade nova para listar os clientes do banco de dados e editar, você poderia criar um novo branch chamado **clientes** e trabalhar nesse branch para depois jogar ao master

**clone**

Como a própria palavra diz é um **clone**. Esse comando serve para você clonar repositórios de uma outra pessoa. No github você pode clonar repositórios digitando no **console** do seu sistema operacional **git clone URL_DO_REPOSITORIO**

**track**

Creio que aqui você fala da área de **untrack files**. Quando você inicia o git e logo após isso você começa a editar arquivos nessa pasta que você iniciou o git ou também coloca novas arquivos então ele fica como **untrack files** (arquivos não trackeados) que é arquivos não "vigiados" pelo git, ou seja, que não estão ainda na pasta **.git** ou que estão e foram modificados. Quando você da um **git add .** ou **git add arquivo.extensao** ele entra para o **track files** que significa que o git ta olhando mas ainda não está no repositório git. Só depois que você da **git commit -m "descrição do commit"** é que ele sai dessa área e entra totalmente para o repositório git.

Não sei se deu para entender muito bem, mas tentei explicar com minhas palavras. Segue um link para os primeiros passos no **git**

[#1 Primeiros Passos com Git](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html)

[#2 Comandos básicos do Git](http://tableless.com.br/iniciando-no-git-parte-1/)

Comment: O track é no contexto de branch. Parece que todo `git clone` cria uma [_`remote-tracking branches`_](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone). E tem o argumento `--track` para varios comandos do Git.