# Por que usar Git para desenvolvimento individual?

Tags: git, versionamento, svn, gerenciamento-de-projetos

Em 2008 eu fiz uma pergunta no SO sobre controle de versão para desenvolvedor solo e recebi uma excelente resposta do Jon Skeet indicando o uso do SVN. Infelizmente recentemente ela foi fechada e removida.

Hoje o Git está se tornando ubíquo. Isto por si só traz algumas vantagens. Se você usa alguns projetos *open source* de terceiros provavelmente já é pelo menos cliente de Git.

Eu vejo o Git como algo complexo para quem precisa de controle de versão simplificadamente. Mas admito que existem algumas vantagens também.

Objetivamente, o que é realmente determinante para escolher trocar o SVN pelo Git em um cenário de desenvolvimento individual? Que característica matadora pode definir esta escolha? Lembre-se que algumas das vantagens do Git não se aplicam a este cenário.

Há vantagem nisso? Vou perder alguma coisa significativa com a troca?

Comment: Põe o link mesmo assim. Quem tiver reputação suficiente por lá poderá ver a pergunta original. Posta a resposta do Jon Skeet também.

Comment: @Victor, foi removido mesmo, dá 404 e não aparece no meu perfil. Ficou anos lá sem atrapalhar ninguém com vários votos, de repente, alguém resolveu que não servia. Eu nem soube porque foi fechada e porque foi removida em definitivo tão rápido. Não tinha nada errado na pergunta.

Comment: Eu sou uma pessoa extremamente desorganizada, sempre acabo fazendo um monte de cópias das pastas dos meus projetos (pra backup, pra testar em outros ambientes, etc). Um sistema de controle de versões descentralizado (assim como o Git, embora eu que eu uso é o Mercurial) quebra um galhão nesse caso - principalmente porque eu nem sempre tenho o "repositório oficial" na mesma rede de onde eu faço as cópias. Um sistema com servidor centralizado não me traria muito benefício, ao passo que um descentralizado me permite mesclar as mudanças de um ambiente pro outro sem virar bagunça...

Comment: O engraçado é que uma pergunta subjetiva dessas ficou: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138621/best-version-control-for-lone-developer

Comment: Eu conheço o Git razoavelmente, tanto que até respondi aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43894/101

Comment: Às vezes o git é até mais fácil para uso sozinho. Por exemplo: pode ficar tudo no .git, não é obrigatório criar um repositório separado (como "servidor"), e desfazer ações (inclusive commits) é considerado parte normal do fluxo de trabalho e bem documentado (não que seja impossível com outras ferramentas).

Comment: Eu uso GIT programando sozinho. Sei apenas o bê-a-bá e me envergonho em dizer que não sei trabalhar em grupo com ele. Poxa, as vezes eu me enrolo até comigo mesmo (*denied fast-forwards*). Todos os tutoriais que encontro focam mais na parte técnica, em diagramas do quê está acontecendo nos bastidores, mas esquecem que algumas pessoas tem dificuldade de interpretar esse tipo de coisa. Pena que não é o escopo do tópico porque seria um tema bastante interessante pra ser no KB.

Answer (score 27):

Bom, eu vou contar um pouco o que me convence que o Git com certeza veio para ficar entre as melhores (senão a melhor) formas de versionamento - e isto incluí desenvolvimento individual.

Provavelmente você já deve ter lido sobre as vantagens do Git, a sua história etc. Se isto ainda não te convenceu, vou relembrar algumas coisas interessantes:

- ***Feature branching*** - Embora esta é mais uma técnica de versionamento do que algo próprio no Git, é incrivelmente fácil fazer isso no Git! Desenvolver *solo* as vezes pode nos levar a perder muito tempo em algo não muito útil... enquanto estamos desenvolvendo algo surge uma ideia incrível, mais fácil.. só que como está no meio de outra acaba deixando isso pra depois. Pode ser algo que acontece só comigo, mas é muito mais fácil fazer um branch para uma nova *feature* e seguir desenvolvendo em outro *branch* quando surgir outra ideia!
- ***Velocidade*** - Não dá para comparar a velocidade do Git. É extremamente rápido! Por favor não me diga que você usa o Tortoise no Windows! Ele é incrivelmente simples, mas não conheço um computador com Windows e Tortoise que me deixa feliz quando clico o botão direito do mouse. Vamos ser práticos.. isso é irritante mesmo. Além do mais, o projeto pode até ser pequeno, mas tente começar a fazer comparações de arquivos entres *branches*... ou pior, tente encontrar uma *string* específica no histórico de versões! Isto é bem doloroso... Comparações entre inteiras versões no Git é bem legal também!
- ***Histórico*** - Eu não sei a maneira como você configura o seu SVN, mas ter todo o histórico local é incrível! Duplicar este histórico de maneira rápida, simples (um comando) e com todos arquivos bem comprimidos também é bem incrível. Isto te salva de um monte de dor de cabeças quando você precisar olhar um histórico e seu servidor não estiver disponível.
- ***Tamanho da base*** - Armazenar um repositório em Git é ótimo. Acho que nem preciso descrever. Para quem vai e volta de versão o tempo todo também, ou têm muitos binários (eu tenho) dentro de algum *library* (eu sou do tipo prevenido, tenho todas as minhas dependências comitadas), isso é importantíssimo! Como o Git trabalha com *hashes* e linhas diferentes de versionamento de arquivo e de histórico, você pode ter duplicações de arquivos o tanto que quiser que o repositório não vai crescer. E ele mantém o histórico tranquilamente nesses arquivos.
- ***Github*** - Sem comentários. É excelente para projetos individuais. Possui ferramentas visuais para Windows e outras plataformas bem intuitivas.
- ***Facilidade*** - Pode descartar todas mudanças do repositório com 1 comando.. vai fazer uma mudança drástica e só quer tentar? Duplique o repositório com 1 comando e sem um servidor. Faça *commits* locais e depois mande tudo para um *server* com 2 comandos.
- ***Gitk - Blame*** - Isso salva empregos. Sem mais comentários. Sei que existe isso no SVN/CVS (se chama `annotate`). Mas acho o do Git bem mais fácil de usar e mais rápido.

Já listei algumas talvez alguém pudesse acrescentar outras. Existe muita gente com *medo* do Git porque não tem nada muito visual... digamos o seguinte, programar é algo para profissionais. Por que não investir um pouco em entender e usar o Git?

O Git sim tem algumas coisas a mais que exige um tempo a mais para aprender. Sempre achei o SVN/CVS simples demais... São bons para proteção (parecem como uma pasta de rede compartilhada. Na madrugada alguém vai lá e faz uma cópia.. nem todo mundo gosta disso, mas esse é o meu sentimento trabalhando com CVS/SVN). Nada melhor do que começar em casa! Tão logo quanto surgir algumas dificuldades (e memorizar um ou outro comando) vai ser tão simples quando usar algo visual... alguns comandos no terminal podem equivaler muito tempo olhando versões no SVN/CVS.

Comment: A resposta está interessante mas o foco da pergunta é para o desenvolvedor solo. Tentar atender mais esse ponto.

Comment: @bigown Acho que este foi o foco da minha resposta destacando apenas features que acredito que sejam interessantes quando se está desenvolvendo solo. Como já dito, velocidade, tamanho da base e feature branching no git são bem interessantes.

Comment: Por que "sem comentários" pro GitHub?

Comment: @rodrigogq entendi. Não consegui enxergar assim, vou reler.

Comment: @renan acho que assim fica mais claro.

Answer (score 5):

A resposta do Rodrigo traz diversas vantagens do Git, então minha resposta vai mais como complemento, tentando cobrir alguns outros pontos.

Entendo que o Git acaba sendo a opção padrão mesmo para projetos individuais por alguns motivos:

- **Experiência**. Provavelmente o desenvolvedor já trabalhou em um projeto que usa Git. E se não trabalhou, certamente vale aprender pois este conhecimento será certamente usado em sua carreira profissional ao participar de novos projetos ou trabalhando em outras empresas. O mesmo não pode se dizer de outros versionadores.
- **O "baú" (stash)**. É muito simples guardar para depois aquele código que você (acha que) precisará mais tarde usando o comando `git stash` e voltar com ele todo com `git stash pop`. Não sei se outros versionadores tem algo parecido, mas é um recurso muito útil.
- ***Staging Area***: se você for uma pessoa que gosta das coisas muito bem organizadas, você pode usar o *Staging Area* do Git para separar em [diferentes commits](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/320850/4492) as diversas alterações realizadas no código, sem se preocupar se outro desenvolvedor está achando um exagero :)

Há mais dois pontos ainda, que explicarei melhor abaixo: **facilidade de criar um repositório** e **facilidade de entendimento**.

Sobre a **facilidade de criar um repositório**, para mim não existe nada mais simples do que chegar no diretório raiz do seu projeto solo e fazer:

```
git init
```

E ter imediatamente, sem configurar nada a mais, um repositório Git totalmente funcional para aquele seu projeto solo, podendo usufruir de todas as ferramentas que o Git oferece.

Agora, imaginemos o cenário de um desenvolvedor que nunca viu Git na vida.

Normalmente muitos acabam pensando como alternativa o SVN. Mas talvez colocar um repositório SVN para funcionar não seja tão simples quanto simplesmente aprender a usar o Git.

Posto isto, vamos as dúvidas:

> Objetivamente, o que é realmente determinante para escolher trocar o SVN pelo Git em um cenário de desenvolvimento individual? Que característica matadora pode definir esta escolha? Lembre-se que algumas das vantagens do Git não se aplicam a este cenário.

Pelas razões que expliquei acima, pode acabar sendo mais trabalhoso colocar um SVN para funcionar do que simplesmente criar um repositório local e aprender Git. E se você já conhece Git, não vejo vantagens em usar SVN na maioria dos cenários.

> Há vantagem nisso? Vou perder alguma coisa significativa com a troca?

Agora, finalmente, explicarei sobre o que eu disse sobre **facilidade de entendimento** do Git. Talvez os comandos do Git não sejam muito amigáveis, mas o seu funcionamento interno é bem mais claro (ao menos para mim).

Minha experiência com SVN é antiga (meados de 2011). Na época eu consegui entender muito melhor como o Git funcionava do que como o SVN funcionava, e isto em um intervalo muito curto de tempo. Com o Git você simplesmente pode pensar no seu repositório como um grande grafo, o que facilita no entendimento de diversos cenários do repositório de uma forma visual.

Vou dar um exemplo de como o SVN pode ser confuso e, de antemão, peço perdão por não trazer mais detalhes, pois faz muito tempo que isto ocorreu comigo.

No SVN, ás vezes precisávamos pegar revisões individuais de uma branch de uma *tarefa* qualquer e passar para uma outra branch de *release*. Após isto, fazíamos o merge da branch da *tarefa* na branch de *release* e o SVN simplesmente ignorava no merge todos as revisões da tarefa anteriores a aquela revisão individual. Sei que isto é um comportamento de *merge*, mas o fato do SVN permitir selecionar um *range* de revisões (ou  revisões individualmente) neste processo de merge deixava a situação bem confusa.

Quando passei a finalmente entender como o Git era mais simples neste mesmo cenário, usando `cherry-pick`, e deixando claro a diferença dele para o *merge* ou *rebase*, passei a simpatizar com a ferramenta :).

Answer (score 3):

Vale também ressaltar que diferentemente do CVS e SVN que são sistemas de versionamento centralizados, o Git é um sistema de versionamento distribuído e isso faz com que ele apresente as seguintes, vantagens:

- menos processamento é exigido, tendo em vista que a todo commit não é necessário interagir com servidor central, em equipes com muitos desenvolvedores isso é um fator bem importante;
- maior rapidez tendo em vista que operações como commit, diff e log
  são executadas localmente;
- apresenta maior autonomia pois todas as operaçõespodem ser executadas localmente sendo necessário o uso a rede somente para troca de revisões com o repositório remoto(exemplo push do que já foi concluído, pull de novas revisões);
- custo de processamento reduzido pois o processmento  fica distribuído na máquina dos próprios desenvolvedores;
- a confiabilidade aumenta pois existe um backup mais ou menos atualizado na máquina de cada desenvolvedor, que no caso do centralizado em caso de crash interrompe todo o desenvolvimento.

Um adendo não obrigatório é o fluxo de trabalho, que acho bem interessante, que é o GitFlow, bem descrito em:

> https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow