# SVN - Sublime Text 3

Tags: svn, sublime-text

Estou utilizando o Sublime Text 3 para desenvolvimento e estou necessitando de um bom SVN.

Atualmente estou usando o [SVN](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/svn/usage), contudo o sistema de comparação de arquivos dele não me agradou muito, encontrei também o [Sublimerge](http://www.sublimerge.com/), este parece muito bom, mas é pago.

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem algum para recomendar?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8315/10315, aqui tem alguns exemplos e difrenças veja se te ajuda. @GuilhermeLautert

Comment: devia tentar mudar para `GIT`, o que odeio em SVN é que para ver histórico, fazer comit, etc precisa sempre de estar ligado a um servidor... no GIT faz tudo localmente e só quando quiser é que faz o `push` para o servidor (repositório remoto). Mas na altura de eu usar SVN, usava o http://beanstalkapp.com/