# Qual é a diferença entre SVN e TFS?

Tags: versionamento, team-foundation-server, svn, tortoisesvn

Sempre usei SVN para versionar os artefatos mas me mudei de emprego e a empresa a qual estou trabalhando usa TFS para fazer o versionamento e não sei o que esse TFS faz exatamente.

1. Qual é a diferença entre eles?
2. Vantagens e desvantagens.
3. Qual é o melhor?

Answer (score 4):

Ele faz essencialmente a mesma coisa que o SVN faz, mas de outra forma. Vai ter que aprender todo seu fluxo e suas especificidades. Não dá para dizer tudo em uma pergunta, mas perguntas específicas são bem-vindas.

Ele é um produto mais completo, o SVN cuida só do controle de versão, o TFS é um Application Life-cycle Management, então ele cuida de todo o fluxo de desenvolvimento. O SVN precisa de ferramentas auxiliares como controle de *tickets* de *bug* para fazer outras tarefas. Ele pode por exemplo, forçar certas políticas de como proceder com o código sendo alterado. Ele pode ter mais controle (auditoria) de tudo o que foi feito, provavelmente o que faz as pessoas escolherem ele, mas você tem menos controle do que pode fazer.

Muitas das vantagens são baseadas em opiniões, dizer qual é o melhor é mais ainda. Isto não fazemos aqui.

Alguns dizem que é mais fácil fazer *merge* no TFSVC (uma das opções de controle de versão do TFS). Já vi relatos de pesadelos e que o SVN é mais simples. Em compensação o TFS permite usar o Git que faz o *merge* de forma simples.

Não vou comparar o Git com o SVN porque isto [já foi feito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8315/101).

A terminologia do SVN e do TFVC muda um pouco e o fluxo pode ser um pouco diferente (*check in/check out* contra *commit/update*), mas essencialmente o controle de versão pode ser feito da mesma forma.

O TFS esperava que o desenvolvedor esteja sempre conectado ao servidor, mas versões mais recentes melhoraram isto. Certifique-se de estar usando uma versão mais moderna.

Outras diferenças são irrelevantes para a pergunta já que a decisão já está tomada. Nem vou falar sobre custo, melhor integração com o VS, diferenças de implantação.

De uma maneira geral as pessoas consideram ele uma solução mais *enterprise* e o SVN é mais comunitário. Não tem nada de errado em usar um ou outro, é uma questão de cultura do local de onde trabalha. Ambos são centralizados. ao contrário do Git que é descentralizado.

Pode ser que algum recurso específico de um pode ser fundamental para uma equipe. Pode ser que a escolha seja feita por questões "políticas", como sempre preferir produtos da Microsoft. Alguns usam mais pelos recursos de gerenciamento do projeto, outros pela forma de controle mais centralizado do TFSVC. Os que gostam do ALM em geral mas preferem um controle de versão "mais flexível" optar pelo Git dentro do TFS.

O SVN é uma solução mais leve. Porém hoje muitas pessoas preferem usar o Git isolado sem o TFS como controle de versão mais leve.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Alguns mitos na sua resposta: O TFS não é preciso ficar conectado o tempo todo com o desenvolvedor, tanto no Git, que já é um DVCS, então não precisao mesmo; como no TFVC, que funciona também desconectado, apesar de não permitir check-in local. O TFS também funciona com outras IDE's ou linguagens que não o VS, tanto o Git como TFVC.

Comment: Você tem alguma referência sobre isto? Todas que eu tenho dizem isto.

Comment: Você encontra informações sobre Workspance local, que permite utilizar o TFVC sem estar conectado, porém é importante frisar, não é possível fazer check-in local, lembre-se ele é um CVCS; aqui https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx#workspace_server_offline e informação sobre o TE para Eclipse está aqui https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913026(v=vs.120).aspx... outras plataformas, por exemplo, ObjectiveC usa-se Git do TFS, e aí a instação é o Git para Mac, que baixa no site oficial https://git-scm.com/ e as outras funcionalidades usa-se o Web Access.

Comment: @egomesbrandao tens razão, dei uma melhorada, veja se está ok agora, obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

O TFS, Team Foundation Server, é uma plataforma de Application Lifecycle Management. Plataforma por que sua arquitetura é distribuída, então na configuração mais simples é possível ter um único servidor com vários serviços rodando, e em uma mais complexa um servidor central, mais servidores de build, de deploy, de relatórios, entre outros. Ele está incluso na licença MSDN, mais comum em empresas, ou seja, se você tem uma licença Visual Studio com MSDN, você tem um TFS, e que pode ser usado por toda a equipe. Maiores detalhes de licenciamento, veja [Microsoft Visual Studio Licensing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350). Também existe uma versão Community, para até 5 usuários, de uso grátis.
O SVN é um gerenciador de código fonte centralizado, CVCS, e... só! Ele não faz build, deploy, etc... 
Dito isto, não faz sentido a comparação entre um e outro diretamente, vamos comparar então o SVN com o versionador de código fonte do TFS, que contém 2 tipos. Isso mesmo, no TFS você pode escolher, ao criar um Team Project para hospedar o código da sua aplicação, entre 2 versionadores:

- TFVC, Team Foundation Version Control, que é o versionador que vem desde a versão de lançamento do TFS, antes chamado apenas de Version Control, ele é um CVCS, ou seja, é centralizado. E tem um modo de trabalho desconectado, também! Mas como é centralizado não é possível fazer check-in local.
- Git, que foi adicionado na versão 2013 do TFS, por isso o anterior mudou de nome, e ele é um DVCS, ou seja, descentralizado, por isso, permite commit local.

Apesar de o TFS oferecer uma integração com a IDE Visual Studio (VS), através do Team Explorer (TE), ele não é de uso exclusivo do Visual Studio. Existe uma versão do TE para Eclipse, e também é possível utilizar o TFS com Deplhi, Python, Ruby, ObjectiveC e em um Mac, etc... Ele é agnóstico de linguagem, e com o Git, fica integrado com a IDE do ObjectiveC, pois é possível utilizar o Git original e mesmo assim se comunicar com o TFS para enviar código. Todas as outras funcionalidades estão no portal Web Access, então até mesmo de um Linux você pode utilizar o TFS.

Além da versão Community, para testar o produto sem fazer nenhuma instalação, é possível utilizar para até 5 usuários, também, a versão [SaaS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_como_servi%C3%A7o), sem custo! Que tem as mesmas funcionalidades do TFS [on-premises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-premises_software). Pode-se começar pequeno com essa versão, e se for necessário aumentar o número de usuário será cobrado por cada um que entrar.