# Qual a diferença entre Team Foundation Service e Git?

Tags: git, versionamento, team-foundation-server

Quero saber a diferença entre Git e TFS, pois não entendi se os dois são sistemas de controle de versão ou apenas o Git é um sistema de controle de versão enquanto o TFS é uma aplicação web para hospedar repositórios Git.

Comment: Relacionada: [Diferenças entre Git, SVN e CVS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8315/28595)

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a diferença entre SVN e TFS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108465/28595)

Answer (score 4):

O TFS, Team Foundation Server, e não Service, é uma plataforma de Application Lifecycle Management. Plataforma por que sua arquitetura é distribuída, então na configuração mais simples é possível ter um único servidor com vários serviços rodando, e em uma mais complexa um servidor central, mais servidores de build, de deploy, de relatórios, entre outros. Ele está incluso na licença MSDN, mais comum em empresas, ou seja, se você tem uma licença Visual Studio com MSDN, você tem um TFS, e que pode ser usado por toda a equipe. Maiores detalhes de licenciamento, veja [Microsoft Visual Studio Licensing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350). Também existe uma versão Community, para até 5 usuários, de uso grátis.

Já o Git é um DVCS, ou seja Distributed Version Control System, ou seja um versionador de código fonte descentralizado, e... só! Ele não faz build, deploy, etc... Dito isto, não faz sentido a comparação entre um e outro diretamente, vamos comparar então o Git com o versionador de código fonte do TFS, que contém 2 tipos. Isso mesmo, no TFS você pode escolher, ao criar um Team Project para hospedar o código da sua aplicação, entre 2 versionadores:

- TFVC, Team Foundation Version Control, que é o versionador que vem desde a versão de lançamento do TFS, antes chamado apenas de Version Control, ele é um CVCS, ou seja, é centralizado. E tem um modo de trabalho desconectado, também! Mas como é centralizado não é possível fazer check-in local.
- Git, que foi adicionado na versão 2013 do TFS, por isso o anterior mudou de nome, e ele é um DVCS, ou seja, descentralizado, por isso, permite commit local.

Apesar de o TFS oferecer uma integração com a IDE Visual Studio (VS), através do Team Explorer (TE), ele não é de uso exclusivo do Visual Studio. Existe uma versão do TE para Eclipse, e também é possível utilizar o TFS com Deplhi, Python, Ruby, ObjectiveC e em um Mac, etc... Ele é agnóstico de linguagem, e com o Git, fica integrado com a IDE do ObjectiveC, pois é possível utilizar o Git original e mesmo assim se comunicar com o TFS para enviar código. Todas as outras funcionalidades estão no portal Web Access, então até mesmo de um Linux você pode utilizar o TFS.

Além da versão Community, para testar o produto sem fazer nenhuma instalação, é possível utilizar para até 5 usuários, também, a versão [SaaS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_como_servi%C3%A7o), sem custo! Que tem as mesmas funcionalidades do TFS [on-premises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-premises_software), o Visual Studio Team Services, esse sim com o Services no final. Pode-se começar pequeno com essa versão, e se for necessário aumentar o número de usuário será cobrado por cada um que entrar.

Answer (score 3):

Ambos são controladores de versões que podemos dizer que são concorrentes.

Em essência é a mesma diferença entre o Git e SVN. Git é descentralizado e o TFS é centralizado. Claro, a filosofia de trabalho deles é toda diferente. Um é para usar com o Visual Studio junto (ainda que possa usar sem ele), o outro segue a linha de trabalho do Linux.

Por isto algumas operações são mais complicados em um do que em outro.

O TFS tem mais controle sobre o acesso, é possível lidar com mais granularidade e lida melhor com arquivos grandes, só para citar os principais pontos. Em geral trabalha melhor com o projeto conectado no repositório. Ele possui uma solução mais completa de gerenciamento de versão e gerenciamento do projeto.

O Git trabalha melhor com *merge* e costuma ser mais rápido na maioria das operações. Ele é feito para trabalhar *offline*. É mais difícil trabalhar com ele.

Repositórios TFS e Git não são diretamente compatíveis.

TFS tem uma versão web para acessar o código e outros artefatos do projeto. O Git tem algo parecido fornecido por terceiros.

O TFS faz parte do que se chama [ALM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_lifecycle_management) de forma ampla, já o Git sozinho é só uma pequena parte do gereciamento do ciclo de vida do projeto. Então a comparação entre eles só se dá na parte do controle de versão.

O TFS pode ser usado como gerenciador de projetos para um repositório Git, mas não é comum.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).