# Como compartilhar um projeto Java com uma equipe?

Tags: java, versionamento

Alguém conhecem algum versionador que permita trabalhar em equipe usando Java?

Por exemplo, um [Word Online](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx?ui=pt-BR&s=1&auth=0&lc=1046), em que todos mudam o arquivo em tempo real, e as mudanças ficam salvas no servidor.

Comment: Acho que o SVN atende https://tortoisesvn.net/

Comment: Gabriel, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Poderia definir melhor sua pergunta? Você quer uma ferramenta para trabalhar com código em equipe ou um editor online em tempo real?

Comment: Quero editor online em tempo real. A ferramenta para trabalhar em equipe já sei pois a galera já respondeu, agora quero saber um editor online em tempo real.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Se você deseja hospedar seu código fonte na nuvem e não quer desembolsar
um bom cascalho pra isso essa pode ser a solução que você procura.

#### TOP 5 REPOSITÓRIOS DE CÓDIGO FONTE GRÁTIS PARA O SEU SOFTWARE.

[Github – git](http://github.com/) O mais conhecido de todos, tem até o fonte hospedado o código fonte do GNU/Linux, pode se dizer que esse é a primeira opção que vem a cabeça quando se pensa em repositório de código fonte para projetos livre. É grátis para projetos públicos.

[TFS – Team Foundation Service](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-relnotes), é a conhecida plataforma de gerenciamento de código fonte e colaboração da Microsoft que foi parar na nuvem.

Quando pensamos em TFS geralmente nos vem o nome Team Foundation Server, afinal trata-se de uma plataforma local, interna e instalada em um servidor.

A Microsoft há algum tempo disponibilizou esta mesma ferramenta só que hospedada na [nuvem](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/devops/server/), ou seja, nos servidores do [Windows Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/free/search/?&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIkd2vuaqK7QIVEgmRCh1r3gqMEAAYASAAEgIqYfD_BwE:G:s&OCID=AID2100014_SEM_EAIaIQobChMIkd2vuaqK7QIVEgmRCh1r3gqMEAAYASAAEgIqYfD_BwE:G:s).

O famoso TFS passou a ser disponibilizado como serviço, notem que está cada vez mais comum encontrar os “SaaS” Software as a Service, diversos produtos da Microsoft já foram para nuvem (ex Office 365).

[Google Code – subversion](http://code.google.com/), *mercurial e git*. Não é tão badalado como o Github, mas é muito relevante na comunidade de projetos de Software Livre, é comum você ver em projetos, caso você queira pegar a versão mais atualizada um endereço pra você fazer o update do projetos pelo SVN. Grátis para projetos públicos com até 1 giga.

[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) – *git e mercurial*. Não tem limites para quantidade de repositórios privados, a sua limitação é na quantidade de desenvolvedores contribuindo no projeto, que é de 5 que é um tamanho razoável para times de software, um outro destaque é a integração com o JIRA, pra você *trackear* os insetos do seu projeto projeto.

[Assembla – subversion e git](http://assembla.com/) Meio Giga de código fonte e com repositórios privados grátis, para hospedar projetos de *freelance* que não querem ser expostos essa é uma boa opção.

Espero que tenha gostado da dica e não deixe mais seu código fonte sem versionamento, nem mesmo se você for um exercito de um homem só, ou mulher.

Comment: Então, descobri que o netbeans possui um plugin que trabalha com CVS, então posso pegar o repositório do github né isso? Para trabalhar em cima dele...tou vendo uns tutoriais

Comment: O github é bem completo, na versão paga, o projeto pode ficar secreto. Muitos usam, são muitos os benefícios. +1

Comment: @GabrielTI, não conheço o plugin do netbens, mas você pode criar uma conta no github gratuita e por sua aplicação lá, só vai ficar como publicar. se você quiser algo mais privado só pagando mesmo.

Comment: caso queira criar um projeto privado com git da pra utilizar o [gitlab](http://gitlab.com/)

Comment: Pelo o que vi o git atende as minhas necessidades, pois estou realizando projetos iniciantes ainda. Mas o git ainda serve para projetos avançados também?

Comment: O Google code já era.

Answer (score 13):

Para trabalho em equipe e até mesmo sozinho é interessante utilizar uma ferramenta para controle e versionamento até para manter um *backup* de seu código. [Nas respostas dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8322/7461), você pode entender um pouco melhor sobre o **cvs**, **git** e **svn**.

Qualquer uma das três alternativas atende sua necessidade, veja de acordo com sua afinidade.

Por ser menos complicado e poder ser utilizado em conjunto com plataformas como [github](http://github.com) e [gitlab](http://gitlab.com), eu recomendo utilizar o **git** a projetos iniciantes

Answer (score 5):

Completando a resposta, não podemos esquecer do [gitlab](http://gitlab.com). É um ótimo repositório git e atende muito bem a comunidade java.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que o git é uma das formas mais fáceis, se você usa o Eclipse ou o Netbeans ambos possuem plugins de SVN ou Git. E é bem fácil de utilizar.

Um link bom de vídeo-aulas no Youtube.
[Tutorial de Git Básico](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVLhm1AMeYE&list=PLInBAd9OZCzzHBJjLFZzRl6DgUmOeG3H0)

Espero ter ajudado.